# Python Selenium: How do I print the values from a website in a text file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm trying to write a script that will grab the following 6 values from the website tulsaspca.org and print them in a .txt file.

[image: 6 Values]

The final output should be:

```
905 
4896
7105
23194
1004
42000
```

HTML for "Animals Placed"

```
<span class="number" data-to="905">905</span>
</div>
<p class="title">Animals Placed</p>
```

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```py
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Animals Placed'):
  print(element.text)
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML code ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I have the 3 lines and the screenshot. Should I add more lines?

Comment: Please replace the screenshot with the text of the html code.

Comment: Please check out the solution below. Also, Agree with Karel. It's easy for us to look into text rather than seeing an image.

Comment: You are missing the part where each of them are in some sort of list. So you can grab it in a xpath where it goes //span[@class='number']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the six values from the website [*TULSASPCA*](https://tulsaspca.org/) and print them in a text file you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and then using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945168/access-to-table-objects-on-webpage-using-python-selenium/69947765#69947765) you can create a list and subsequently create a [DataFrame](https://favtutor.com/blogs/list-to-dataframe-python) and finally export the values to a *TEXT* file excluding the Index using the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
driver.get("https://tulsaspca.org/")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250)")
# read into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([my_elem.get_attribute("data-to") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='number']")))])
# Exporting as TEXT file excluding the Index
df.to_csv("C:\\Data_Files\\output_files\\new_text_marks.txt", index=False)
driver.quit()
```

Snapshot of Output Text file:

[image: panda_output_text]

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
```

PS: You may like to [drop the first row](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-drop-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-by-index-labels/) from the [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see HTML for all 6 numbers.

But for this HTML

```
<span class="number" data-to="905">905</span>
</div>
<p class="title">Animals Placed</p>
```

Your script should look something like this :

**XPath**

```
//p[text()='Animals Placed']/preceding-sibling::div/span[@class='number']
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
animal_num = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[text()='Animals Placed']/preceding-sibling::div/span[@class='number']").text
print(animal_num)
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
animal_num = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Animals Placed']/preceding-sibling::div/span[@class='number']"))).text
print(animal_num)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update:**

Please use the below xpath

```
//span[@class='number' and @data-to]
```

it should represent all the number of nodes in HTML DOM.

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://tulsaspca.org/")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250)")
all_numbers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='number' and @data-to]")
for number in all_numbers:
    print(number.text)
```

**Output :**

```
905
4896
7105
23194
1004
42000
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I ran it and I'm getting "25". Any ideas? https://i.imgur.com/JMB2pjL.png

Comment: Please check the updated 1 code above for all the list items.

Comment: It also needed some scrolling as well to let selenium knows where exactly are the web elements. Please refer updated 1 code.