# Scraping Table from Website with Selenium Returning Empty DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I just start learning web scraping and trying to extract data from the 'Holdings' table from https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf

First, I use pandas but it returns me empty dataframe. I found out later that this table is dynamic and I need to use selenium. But then again, it also returns me empty dataframe. Could anyone help me with this please? Will really appreciate it.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Instantiate options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True

# Instantiate a webdriver
site = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf'
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get(site)

# Load the HTML page
html = wd.page_source

# Extract data with pandas
df = pd.read_html(html)
table = df[6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the data from the **Holdings** table of [iShares Global REIT ETF](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf) webpage you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and using [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126393/selenium-web-scraping-historical-data-from-coincodex-and-transform-into-a-panda/70128927#70128927) from [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206678/scraping-dynamic-data-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/70207528#70207528) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

wd.get("https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf")
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-componentname]/h2[normalize-space()='Holdings']"))))
data = WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='allHoldingsTable_info']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df  = pd.read_html(data)
# df  = pd.read_html(data, flavor='html5lib')
print(df)
```

Console Output:

```
[  Ticker                                Name       Sector Asset Class  ...      CUSIP          ISIN    SEDOL  Accrual Date
0    PLD                   PROLOGIS REIT INC  Real Estate      Equity  ...  74340W103  US74340W1036  B44WZD7             -
1   EQIX                    EQUINIX REIT INC  Real Estate      Equity  ...  29444U700  US29444U7000  BVLZX12             -
2    PSA                 PUBLIC STORAGE REIT  Real Estate      Equity  ...  74460D109  US74460D1090  2852533             -
3    SPG       SIMON PROPERTY GROUP REIT INC  Real Estate      Equity  ...  828806109  US8288061091  2812452             -
4    DLR       DIGITAL REALTY TRUST REIT INC  Real Estate      Equity  ...  253868103  US2538681030  B03GQS4             -
5      O             REALTY INCOME REIT CORP  Real Estate      Equity  ...  756109104  US7561091049  2724193             -
6   WELL                       WELLTOWER INC  Real Estate      Equity  ...  95040Q104  US95040Q1040  BYVYHH4             -
7    AVB      AVALONBAY COMMUNITIES REIT INC  Real Estate      Equity  ...  053484101  US0534841012  2131179             -
8    ARE  ALEXANDRIA REAL ESTATE EQUITIES RE  Real Estate      Equity  ...  015271109  US0152711091  2009210             -
9    EQR             EQUITY RESIDENTIAL REIT  Real Estate      Equity  ...  29476L107  US29476L1070  2319157             -

[10 rows x 12 columns]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much DebanjanB. I am not fluent in coding, so I find it quite difficult.

Comment: I try the code but it says "NameError: name 'driver' is not defined", so I put in "driver = webdriver.Chrome()" and it says "WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)"

Comment: @Mango Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I still get error message, saying "NameError: name 'wd' is not defined" Maybe I have to declare 'wd' first or install some thing in my PC?? I am sorry but I am not coder or developer, my coding knowledge is still quite limited =(

Comment: Thank you so much @undetected Selenium, I got it work finally with WebDriver Wait for data to fully loaded. However, the output is somewhat truncated from 400+ rows down to only 10 rows. How should I do to load all the 400+ rows? Your help will be very much appreciated