# Scrape table from the site using selenium or beautifulsoup

Tags: pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

I am trying to parse the able from the site https://octopart.com/mcp3304-bi%2Fp-microchip-407390?r=sp#PriceAndStock.
I have tried using xpath of a table with selenium but it fetches only first row. I have also tried html parse with beautifulsoup but I get unstructured text from table.

Code trials:

```
driver.get('https://octopart.com/search?q=PMEG120G20ELRX&currency=USD&specs=0')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

table=soup.find('table')
for distributor in table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows=distributor.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        data=row.find('td')
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 4):

To scrape the table from the [website](https://octopart.com/search?q=PMEG120G20ELRX&currency=USD&specs=0) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and using [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733548/7429447) from [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70207528/7429447) you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

driver.get('https://octopart.com/search?q=PMEG120G20ELRX&currency=USD&specs=0')
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'part')]//table"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df = pd.read_html(data)
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Console Output:

```
[   Unnamed: 0          Distributor                       SKU  Stock   MOQ  ...     10    100  1,000  10,000  Updated
0         NaN  Future Electronics3                   4128873    500     1  ...  0.260  0.200  0.182   0.170       1d
1         NaN            Digi-Key3  1727-PMEG120G20ELRXCT-ND    488     1  ...  0.378  0.257  0.145   0.145      <1m
2         NaN                  TTI            PMEG120G20ELRX  18000  3000  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN   0.124       1d
3         NaN               Mouser        771-PMEG120G20ELRX   4461     1  ...  0.378  0.258  0.150   0.149      14m
4         NaN              Verical            PMEG120G20ELRX   6000  3000  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN   0.178      <1m

[5 rows x 13 columns]]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. It worked. Just one question though, the output is list with length=1. How can I get in the dataframe format. Eventually, I want to save table as .csv file.

Comment: _list with length=1_: Where is the list? I passed the entire `<table>` HTML to `read_html()` method, which is processed by [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70454194/7429447)

Comment: I got it, it was list with two element, the first element was the actual table. df[0] worked.

Comment: @PyCode Glad to know your issue got resolved.