# Dynamic content from table - can't scrape with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My main goal is to scrape content from the table from this site

```
polygonscan.com/token/0x64a795562b02830ea4e43992e761c96d208fc58d
```

For example, I tried to select content from the table - then I wanted to scrape all the data from the table to a .csv file, but I ran into a problem at the start of this task. I tried to select content from the first row, but it looks like Selenium doesn't see any HTML content from the table area. My code below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Set drive
chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Users\kacpe\OneDrive\Pulpit\Python\Projekty\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://polygonscan.com/token/0x64a795562b02830ea4e43992e761c96d208fc58d")


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[0]")))
    print(element)
except TimeoutException as e:
    print(e)
```

and the error I receive:

```
ile "C:\Users\kacpe\OneDrive\Pulpit\Python\Projekty\nc-coin-scraper\nc_scraper\nc_scraper\spiders\aaa.py", line 29, in <module>
    a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="maindiv"]/div[1]/p').text
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\OneDrive\Pulpit\Python\Projekty\nc-coin-scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\OneDrive\Pulpit\Python\Projekty\nc-coin-scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\OneDrive\Pulpit\Python\Projekty\nc-coin-scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="maindiv"]/div[1]/p"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00EC6903+2517251]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E5F8E1+2095329]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D62848+1058888]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D8D448+1233992]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D8D63B+1234491]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DB7812+1406994]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DA650A+1336586]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DB5BBF+1399743]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DA639B+1336219]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D827A7+1189799]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D83609+1193481]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01055904+1577972]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01100B97+2279047]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F56D09+534521]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F55DB9+530601]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E64FF9+2117625]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E698A8+2136232]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E699E2+2136546]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E73541+2176321]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75DAFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DE7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DE7A6E+238]
```

Any thoughts on how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the data from the **Transfers** table of [Token Natluk Community - polygonscan](https://polygonscan.com/token/0x64a795562b02830ea4e43992e761c96d208fc58d) webpage you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and using [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126393/selenium-web-scraping-historical-data-from-coincodex-and-transform-into-a-panda/70128927#70128927) from [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206678/scraping-dynamic-data-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/70207528#70207528) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://polygonscan.com/token/0x64a795562b02830ea4e43992e761c96d208fc58d")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btnCookie"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#tokentxnsiframe")))
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.table.table-md-text-normal"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df = pd.read_html(data)
print(df)
```

Console Output:

```
[                                             Txn Hash               Method  ...       Quantity Unnamed: 7
0   0x75411962e2e6527f5a032198816cafe4e1a475a4ebdf...  Add Liquidity ET...  ...   37929.272725        NaN
1   0x27f61026e9df4c0c14c6259f624917a12ce7f6c20eb7...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...   50814.040553        NaN
2   0xd9ee0ed46ef8ce891e81787b25176530a30df6d2b98e...  Add Liquidity ET...  ...   55288.744543        NaN
3   0x3f3982a38ff3f5c5890eff12a9d3f7061fea88942d96...  Add Liquidity ET...  ...     978.219682        NaN
4   0x503fad1b044b98c58700d185eb8cb9c16a483fd748d7...              Unstake  ...    8884.911763        NaN
5   0x503fad1b044b98c58700d185eb8cb9c16a483fd748d7...              Unstake  ...    9026.302437        NaN
6   0xdc75ad4e37e232f8536305ef8c628fd9391c1f2c5d25...             Transfer  ...  114000.000000        NaN
7   0x218ae4183e632c47edf581705871a3f16dc32cc513ef...  Add Liquidity ET...  ...   45125.111655        NaN
8   0x9fbe017ebf37aea501050a68c8ab1d78734b576b5585...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...    2563.443420        NaN
9   0xd30adcf551285d4b72495d55cc59ffaed82a224b138c...                Claim  ...   14923.359293        NaN
10  0x65c733e468df90eaed701bc4f1e21a4090924b1225c1...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...   33055.752836        NaN
11  0x82c215000f9807a3a40fe3ef3e461ceac007513b49ff...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...    6483.182959        NaN
12  0x6155da0b5b206a8ffffa300a5d75e23fa3833b9b079b...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...   13005.174783        NaN
13  0x3435579c22e9fc42f6921229449c8cb18d133a207a66...             Transfer  ...   47500.000000        NaN
14  0x7a57be9b538e0c73df4b608a8323c2f678ba6136f9a9...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...   19605.381370        NaN
15  0x8fe7787039c4a382f6420c78b48933dd59b0843c6ab4...             Transfer  ...  237500.000000        NaN
16  0x0e55aa0740f6c964db13efe52e1af58a35497f9a292d...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...    6561.223602        NaN
17  0x9897d4a2f56a49a935a36183eee3dc846fc19610812c...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...   19762.821100        NaN
18  0xf9c7d67bf679624640f20d69636f58f634bf66e7daed...  Add Liquidity ET...  ...   74224.394200        NaN
19  0x89b490947952e37e10a3619f8fbcb5a80b15f0e2f4aa...  Add Liquidity ET...  ...   14589.910231        NaN
20  0xc94e56bb3be04e610c6a89e934fb84bba58922f6641a...             Transfer  ...  142500.000000        NaN
21  0x68a5c142bbfa86b0aa4f469eb17f58e26b5251bd83e9...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...    3307.607665        NaN
22  0x2597e521fd0a7e4edffe66007129c93d1dc22485b86a...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...   66868.030051        NaN
23  0x14cc91039f59fd9143bc94132b9f053970947b79a16f...  Swap Exact Token...  ...   42683.069577        NaN
24  0xa5ab4179af827c6883e52cbc010509b701795a8136a0...  Swap Exact ETH F...  ...    3423.618394        NaN

[25 rows x 8 columns]]
```