# Read all values of HTML table with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read all elements in the following html table and convert it to a dataframe but all the numerical values are not being recorded by my `get_attribute` function. I have also tried with `.get_attribute('td')` ,`.get_attribute('tr')`  and `.get_attribute('outerHTML')` but still get the result below.
I have tried using the following code

```
bond_totals_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/body').get_attribute('td')
bond_totals_table = pd.read_html(bond_totals_table, flavor = 'bs4')
```

```
0   Increment Number    Action  Current Acres   Add Delete  Acres for Calculation   Adjusted Amount Status  Bond?
1   NaN Existing Modify New Closed Reactivate Reconcile NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ACT INA PH1 PH2 PH3 TRM Yes No
2   NaN Existing Modify New Closed Reactivate Reconcile NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ACT INA PH1 PH2 PH3 TRM Yes No
3   NaN Existing Modify New Closed Reactivate Reconcile NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ACT INA PH1 PH2 PH3 TRM Yes No
4   NaN Existing Modify New Closed Reactivate Reconcile NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ACT INA PH1 PH2 PH3 TRM Yes No
5   NaN Existing Modify New Closed Reactivate Reconcile NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ACT INA PH1 PH2 PH3 TRM Yes No
6   NaN Existing Modify New Closed Reactivate Reconcile NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ACT INA PH1 PH2 PH3 TRM Yes No
7   NaN Existing Modify New Closed Reactivate Reconcile NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ACT INA PH1 PH2 PH3 TRM Yes No
```

It seems the table used to be adjustable but not anymore and the `get attribute`function is somehow not getting at the displayed values in the grey cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To read all values of HTML table you need to target the *`<table>`* element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and extract the *`outerHTML`* as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

bond_totals_table_data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table"))).get_attribute('outerHTML')
bond_totals_table = pd.read_html(bond_totals_table_data)
print(bond_totals_table)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Can't find table selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748263/7429447)
- [BeautifulSoup and Pandas read_html is not pulling all of the rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025713/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beautiful Soup w/ Panda.  Here's an example of reading from a CDC table:

```
with webdriver.Firefox() as browser:
    browser.get("https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nhis/shs/tables.htm")
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    tbl = soup.select_one("#example")
    df = pd.read_html(str(tbl))
    print(df[0])
```