# BeautifulSoup and Pandas read_html is not pulling all of the rows in a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, beautifulsoup

When I am scraping a table from a website, it is missing the bottom 5 rows of data and I do not know how to pull them. I am using a combination of BeautifulSoup and Selenium. I thought that they were not loading, so I tried scrolling to the bottom with Selenium, but that still did not work.

Code trials:

```
site = 'https://fbref.com//en/comps/15/10733/schedule/2020-2021-League-One'
PATH = my_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(site)
webpage = bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')

table = webpage.find('table', {'class': 'stats_table sortable min_width now_sortable'})
print(table.prettify())
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

print(df.tail())
```

Please could you help with scraping the full table?

Comment: No need to use selenium here, using `requests` would suffice and be faster. The table isn't being loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) to pull all the rows from the table within the [website](https://fbref.com/en/comps/15/10733/schedule/2020-2021-League-One-Scores-and-Fixtures) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and using [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733548/7429447) from [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70207528/7429447) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  tabledata = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.stats_table.sortable.min_width.now_sortable"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
  tabledf = pd.read_html(tabledata)
  print(tabledf)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://fbref.com//en/comps/15/10733/schedule/2020-2021-League-One')
  data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='stats_table sortable min_width now_sortable']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
  df = pd.read_html(data)
  print(df)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [              Round   Wk  Day  ...             Referee  Match Report                         Notes
  0    Regular Season    1  Sat  ...  Charles Breakspear  Match Report                           NaN
  1    Regular Season    1  Sat  ...       Andrew Davies  Match Report                           NaN
  2    Regular Season    1  Sat  ...       Kevin Johnson  Match Report                           NaN
  3    Regular Season    1  Sat  ...   Anthony Backhouse  Match Report                           NaN
  4    Regular Season    1  Sat  ...        Marc Edwards  Match Report                           NaN
  ..              ...  ...  ...  ...                 ...           ...                           ...
  685     Semi-finals  NaN  Tue  ...       Robert Madley  Match Report                    Leg 1 of 2
  686     Semi-finals  NaN  Wed  ...         Craig Hicks  Match Report                    Leg 1 of 2
  687     Semi-finals  NaN  Fri  ...        Keith Stroud  Match Report     Leg 2 of 2; Blackpool won
  688     Semi-finals  NaN  Sat  ...   Michael Salisbury  Match Report  Leg 2 of 2; Lincoln City won
  689           Final  NaN  Sun  ...     Tony Harrington  Match Report                           NaN

      [690 rows x 13 columns]]
  ```

Comment: Thank you!! This was really helpful.