# How do I Webscrape table with Selenium?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am having trouble scraping a table

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://fantasyteamadvice.com/dfs/nba/ownership")
html = driver.page_source

tm.sleep(8)

tables = pd.read_html(html)
data = tables[0:]

driver.close()

data.to_csv("inputs/dk_ownership.csv")
data
```

***Getting Error below***
ValueError: No tables found

Answer (score 0):

Use webdriverwait and wait for the element visible and find the table element and get the outHTML from the table and then use pandas.

```
waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)
link = "https://fantasyteamadvice.com/dfs/nba/ownership"  
driver.get (link)
html=waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table[data-testid='ownershipTablenba']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
table = pd.read_html(html)[0]
print(table)
table.to_csv("inputs/dk_ownership.csv")
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
```

output of the DF:

```
    Unnamed: 0                   Player Draftkings Price DK NBA Ownership Projection Fanduel Price FD NBA Ownership Projection
0          NaN            Klay Thompson            $8000                        3.3%         $8000                        4.7%
1          NaN          Harrison Barnes            $4900                        1.8%         $4600                        8.6%
2          NaN           Draymond Green            $6800                        1.7%         $6800                        7.3%
3          NaN              Dario Saric            $3500                        0.2%         $4100                        0.2%
4          NaN               Trey Lyles            $3200                        1.1%         $4200                        0.9%
5          NaN             Kevon Looney            $4700                        7.9%         $5700                        4.3%
6          NaN               Cedi Osman            $3100                        0.2%         $4500                        0.2%
7          NaN         Domantas Sabonis            $9900                       10.6%         $9600                       17.0%
8          NaN             Caris Levert            $4500                        1.3%         $5300                        0.2%
9          NaN             De'Aaron Fox            $9000                        3.9%         $9400                        7.4%
10         NaN               Malik Monk            $4800                        3.4%         $5500                        2.7%
11         NaN         Donovan Mitchell            $9700                        7.0%         $9500                        8.0%
12         NaN            Jarrett Allen            $6900                       15.0%         $7600                        7.4%
13         NaN         Donte Divincenzo            $5500                        6.0%         $5300                       13.0%
14         NaN  Shai Gilgeous-Alexander           $10200                       15.6%        $10700                       27.2%
15         NaN            Kevin Huerter            $5300                        4.4%         $6000                        3.3%
16         NaN         Kenrich Williams            $4100                        3.0%         $4700                        2.7%
17         NaN            Terence Davis            $4400                        0.2%         $4800                        0.2%
18         NaN           Darius Garland            $7700                       13.0%         $8400                       17.0%
19         NaN            Luguentz Dort            $4500                        4.2%         $5400                        0.7%
20         NaN                Ty Jerome            $3600                        0.4%         $4400                        0.4%
21         NaN             Jordan Poole            $8300                        6.8%         $8300                       10.3%
22         NaN              Isaac Okoro            $3400                        1.5%         $4200                        1.0%
23         NaN               Isaiah Joe            $3800                        3.6%         $4400                        1.8%
24         NaN         Jonathan Kuminga            $4200                       10.0%         $4100                       16.8%
25         NaN             Anthony Lamb            $3000                        3.3%         $3600                        1.0%
26         NaN         Lindy Waters III            $3100                        0.1%           $--                        0.0%
27         NaN   Jeremiah Robinson-Earl            $3300                        1.0%         $3900                        0.3%
28         NaN              Moses Moody            $3000                        1.0%         $3600                        0.4%
29         NaN          Davion Mitchell            $3000                        0.9%         $3700                        0.2%
30         NaN              Josh Giddey            $7500                        6.0%         $7500                       15.0%
31         NaN              Evan Mobley            $7300                        4.5%         $7400                       13.5%
32         NaN            Keegan Murray            $4900                        2.2%         $5200                        0.7%
33         NaN           Jalen Williams            $6100                        0.9%         $6000                        5.2%
34         NaN          Jaylin Williams            $3400                        0.4%         $4700                        0.1%
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. Instead of passing `driver.page_source` as the data to the [`read_html()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025713/7429447) you need to pass only the *`<table>`* element as follows:

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://fantasyteamadvice.com/dfs/nba/ownership')
  data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[data-testid='ownershipTablenba']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
  df = pd.read_html(data)
  print(df)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  [    Unnamed: 0                   Player  ... Fanduel Price FD NBA Ownership Projection
  0          NaN            Klay Thompson  ...         $8000                        4.7%
  1          NaN          Harrison Barnes  ...         $4600                        8.6%
  2          NaN           Draymond Green  ...         $6800                        7.3%
  3          NaN              Dario Saric  ...         $4100                        0.2%
  4          NaN               Trey Lyles  ...         $4200                        0.9%
  5          NaN             Kevon Looney  ...         $5700                        4.3%
  6          NaN               Cedi Osman  ...         $4500                        0.2%
  7          NaN         Domantas Sabonis  ...         $9600                       17.0%
  8          NaN             Caris Levert  ...         $5300                        0.2%
  9          NaN             De'Aaron Fox  ...         $9400                        7.4%
  10         NaN               Malik Monk  ...         $5500                        2.7%
  11         NaN         Donovan Mitchell  ...         $9500                        8.0%
  12         NaN            Jarrett Allen  ...         $7600                        7.4%
  13         NaN         Donte Divincenzo  ...         $5300                       13.0%
  14         NaN  Shai Gilgeous-Alexander  ...        $10700                       27.2%
  15         NaN            Kevin Huerter  ...         $6000                        3.3%
  16         NaN         Kenrich Williams  ...         $4700                        2.7%
  17         NaN            Terence Davis  ...         $4800                        0.2%
  18         NaN           Darius Garland  ...         $8400                       17.0%
  19         NaN            Luguentz Dort  ...         $5400                        0.7%
  20         NaN                Ty Jerome  ...         $4400                        0.4%
  21         NaN             Jordan Poole  ...         $8300                       10.3%
  22         NaN              Isaac Okoro  ...         $4200                        1.0%
  23         NaN               Isaiah Joe  ...         $4400                        1.8%
  24         NaN         Jonathan Kuminga  ...         $4100                       16.8%
  25         NaN             Anthony Lamb  ...         $3600                        1.0%
  26         NaN         Lindy Waters III  ...           $--                        0.0%
  27         NaN   Jeremiah Robinson-Earl  ...         $3900                        0.3%
  28         NaN              Moses Moody  ...         $3600                        0.4%
  29         NaN          Davion Mitchell  ...         $3700                        0.2%
  30         NaN              Josh Giddey  ...         $7500                       15.0%
  31         NaN              Evan Mobley  ...         $7400                       13.5%
  32         NaN            Keegan Murray  ...         $5200                        0.7%
  33         NaN           Jalen Williams  ...         $6000                        5.2%
  34         NaN          Jaylin Williams  ...         $4700                        0.1%

  [35 rows x 6 columns]]
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```