# How to create a DataFrame with values from dynamic data-index using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape https://www.livescore.com/en/ but I'm facing issue mainly because the structure is different from the others I've already worked on.

I see that there is a dynamic ID that increase the number while scrolling down the page, the id in the code are related only to the visible match on the page, then inside the code the Home team code seems the same compared to the away team code.

This is something I've tried working on

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Lorenzo\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driver.get('https://www.livescore.com/en/football/live/')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()


games1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "MatchRow_matchRowWrapper__1BtJ3"]')
data1 = []
for game1 in games1:
    data1.append({
        'Home':game1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "MatchRow_teamName__2cw5n"]').text,
        'Away':game1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "MatchRow_teamName__2cw5n"]').text,
        'Time':game1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "MatchRowTime_time__2Fkd2 MatchRowTime_isLive__2qWag"]').text
```

The idea is to have a dataframe of the live matches with Home team name, Away team name and actual minute of play

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which is the _Home Team Name_ and _Away Team Name_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733548/7429447) using [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70207528/7429447) with the *Home Team Name* and *Away Team Name* from the [website](https://www.livescore.com/en/) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.livescore.com/en/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  Home_team_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id$='home-team-name']")))]
  Away_team_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id$='away-team-name']")))]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(Home_team_name, Away_team_name)), columns=['Home Team Name', 'Home Team Name'])
  print(df)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
    Home Team Name       Home Team Name
  0  Bayern Munich          FC Salzburg
  1      Liverpool                Inter
  2       FC Porto                 Lyon
  3     Real Betis  Eintracht Frankfurt
  ```

Comment: Hi @undetectedSelenium. Thanks for your reply. Your answer is helpful to catch data but here the issue is that with this flow I can scrape only the visible matches at the beginning. If you check after match n. 3, in the site there are other matches. The code update automatically based on a data-index while scrolling the page.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the clearest and simplest way to locate elements inside elements is to use XPath starting with a dot `.`
The `Home` and `AWAY` team names as well as the match `Time` fields can be clearly located by the following locators:

```py
games1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "MatchRow_matchRowWrapper__1BtJ3"]')
data1 = []
for game1 in games1:
    data1.append({
        'Home':game1.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class,"MatchRow_home")]').text,
        'Away':game1.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class,"MatchRow_away")]').text,
        'Time':game1.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@id,"match-row")]').text
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The main issue is that this code scrape only the visibile matches (after running now the code, I received only 4 records instead of 11). In the HTML there are data-index values that increase every time you scroll the page and each data-indext value is related to a specific match

Comment: I see. We can add a scrolling here, it's not a problem, but I think this will be a new question while I think I answered your original question. In case you agree with this please accept this answer and ask a new, separate question about the scrolling.