# How do I use Selenium to get the menu items and prices for different restaurants by State?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

It's my first time working with Selenium and web scraping. I have been trying to get the menu item and prices for a certain restaurant in California from the following website (https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/). I have been able to use Selenium to get to make it select California from the dropdown menu but I keep running into the problem of not being able to scrape the menu items and prices and coming up with a blank data frame. How do I scrape the menu item and prices from the following website and store them into a data frame? The code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = "/path/to/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path)
url = "https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/"
driver.get(url)
Select(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='tp-variation']")))).select_by_value("MS4yOA==")

print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit

menu = []
prices = []

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup (content, features = "html.parser")

for element in soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'tbody': 'row-hover'}):
    menu = element.find ('td', attrs = {'class': "column-1"})
    prices = element.find('td', attrs = {'class':'column-3'})
    menu.append(menu.text)
    prices.append(prices.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Menu Item':menu, 'Prices':prices})
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The website is using cloudflare protection

```
https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/ is using Cloudflare CDN/Proxy!

https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/ is using Cloudflare SSL!
```

** So I have to use the following options to evade detection

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

*** To select `table tr, td`,I use css selector which is more robust and flexible.

**** I have to use `list and zip` function in pandas DataFrame as it shows not the same shape.

***** I have to use try except as you will see that some menu items are missing

**Script:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

url = "https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/"
driver.get(url)

Select(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='tp-variation']")))).select_by_value("MS4yOA==")



price=[]
menu=[]
 
soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source,"lxml")
driver.close()

for element in soup.select('#tablepress-34 tbody tr'):
    try:
        menus = element.select_one('td:nth-child(2)').text
        menu.append(menus)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        prices = element.select_one('td:nth-child(3) span').text
        price.append(prices)
    except:
        pass
   
 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(price,menu)),columns=['price','menu'])
print(df)
```

[webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

**Output:**

```
    price      menu
0    $2.80     Mini
1    $4.84    Small
2    $5.61   Medium
3    $7.65    Large
4    $2.02     Kids
5    $2.53  Regular
6    $3.81    Large
7    $2.80     Mini
8    $6.39  Regular
9    $7.03
10   $7.03
11   $8.56
12   $7.67
13   $7.67
14   $7.67
15   $7.67
16   $4.47
17   $5.75
18   $6.64
19   $1.01
20   $1.27
21   $2.80
22   $3.57
23   $5.11
24   $1.27
25   $1.91
26   $1.91
27   $4.72     Mini
28   $6.00    Small
29   $7.28   Medium
30   $8.56    Large
31   $4.72     Mini
32   $6.00    Small
33   $7.28   Medium
34   $8.56    Large
35   $0.64
36   $4.72     Mini
37   $6.00    Small
38   $7.28   Medium
39   $8.56    Large
40   $4.72     Mini
41   $6.00    Small
42   $7.28   Medium
43   $8.56    Large
44   $7.67    Quart
45   $6.39     Pint
46  $10.23    Quart
47   $3.70
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
import base64
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for td in soup.select(
    "tr:has(.column-1):has(.column-2):has(.column-3):has(input)"
):
    data.append(
        {
            "Type": td.find_previous(colspan="3").get_text(strip=True),
            "Food": td.select_one(".column-1").get_text(strip=True),
            "Size": td.select_one(".column-2").get_text(strip=True),
            "Price": float(
                td.select_one(".column-3").get_text(strip=True).strip("$")
            ),
        }
    )


adjust = soup.select_one('.tp-variation option:-soup-contains("California")')
adjust = float(base64.b64decode(adjust["value"]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Price"] = (df["Price"] * adjust).round(2)

print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

|  | Type | Food | Size | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Soft Serve Below | Mini | 2.8 |
| 1 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Soft Serve Below | Small | 4.84 |
| 2 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Soft Serve Below | Medium | 5.61 |
| 3 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Soft Serve Below | Large | 7.65 |
| 4 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Cups & Cones | Kids | 2.02 |
| 5 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Cups & Cones | Regular | 2.53 |
| 6 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Cups & Cones | Large | 3.81 |
| 7 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Parfaits | Mini | 2.8 |
| 8 | Soft ServeFlavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, M&M’s, Oreo, Butterfinger, andChocolate Chip Cookie Dough | Parfaits | Regular | 6.39 |
| 9 | Sundaes | Banana Royale |  | 7.03 |
| 10 | Sundaes | Brownie |  | 7.03 |
| 11 | Sundaes | Banana Split |  | 8.56 |
| 12 | Sundaes | Reese’s Peanut Butter Cup Sundae |  | 7.67 |
| 13 | Sundaes | Chocolate Chip Cookie Dough Sundae |  | 7.67 |
| 14 | Sundaes | Oreo® Layered Sundae |  | 7.67 |
| 15 | Sundaes | Made with Snickers Sundae |  | 7.67 |
| 16 | Sundaes | One Scoop Sundae |  | 4.47 |
| 17 | Sundaes | Two Scoops Sundae |  | 5.75 |
| 18 | Sundaes | Three Scoops Sundae |  | 6.64 |
| 19 | Sundaes | Candy Topping |  | 1.01 |
| 20 | Sundaes | Waffle Bowl |  | 1.27 |
| 21 | Ice Cream | Kid’s Scoop |  | 2.8 |
| 22 | Ice Cream | Single Scoop |  | 3.57 |
| 23 | Ice Cream | Double Scoop |  | 5.11 |
| 24 | Ice Cream | Regular Waffle Cone |  | 1.27 |
| 25 | Ice Cream | Chocolate Waffle Cone |  | 1.91 |
| 26 | Ice Cream | Fancy Waffle Cone |  | 1.91 |
| 27 | Beverages | Cappuccino Blast | Mini | 4.72 |
| 28 | Beverages | Cappuccino Blast | Small | 6 |
| 29 | Beverages | Cappuccino Blast | Medium | 7.28 |
| 30 | Beverages | Cappuccino Blast | Large | 8.56 |
| 31 | Beverages | Iced Cappy Blast | Mini | 4.72 |
| 32 | Beverages | Iced Cappy Blast | Small | 6 |
| 33 | Beverages | Iced Cappy Blast | Medium | 7.28 |
| 34 | Beverages | Iced Cappy Blast | Large | 8.56 |
| 35 | Beverages | Add a Boost (Cappuccino or Iced Cappy Blast) |  | 0.64 |
| 36 | Beverages | Smoothie | Mini | 4.72 |
| 37 | Beverages | Smoothie | Small | 6 |
| 38 | Beverages | Smoothie | Medium | 7.28 |
| 39 | Beverages | Smoothie | Large | 8.56 |
| 40 | Beverages | Shake | Mini | 4.72 |
| 41 | Beverages | Shake | Small | 6 |
| 42 | Beverages | Shake | Medium | 7.28 |
| 43 | Beverages | Shake | Large | 8.56 |
| 44 | Ice Cream To Go | Pre-Packed | Quart | 7.67 |
| 45 | Ice Cream To Go | Hand-Packed | Pint | 6.39 |
| 46 | Ice Cream To Go | Hand-Packed | Quart | 10.23 |
| 47 | Ice Cream To Go | Clown Cones |  | 3.7 |

and creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you select ***California*** to extract the table contents within the [website](https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and using [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733548/7429447) from [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70207528/7429447) you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  import pandas as pd

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='tp-variation']")))).select_by_value("MS4yOA==")
  tabledata = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='tablepress-34']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
  tabledf = pd.read_html(tabledata)
  print(tabledf)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [                                                 Food  ...                                              Price
  0   Soft Serve Flavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, ...  ...  Soft Serve Flavors: Reese’s, Heath, Snickers, ...
  1                                    Soft Serve Below  ...                                              $2.80
  2                                    Soft Serve Below  ...                                              $4.84
  3                                    Soft Serve Below  ...                                              $5.61
  4                                    Soft Serve Below  ...                                              $7.65
  5                                        Cups & Cones  ...                                              $2.02
  6                                        Cups & Cones  ...                                              $2.53
  7                                        Cups & Cones  ...                                              $3.81
  8                                            Parfaits  ...                                              $2.80
  9                                            Parfaits  ...                                              $6.39
  10                                            Sundaes  ...                                            Sundaes
  11                                      Banana Royale  ...                                              $7.03
  12                                            Brownie  ...                                              $7.03
  13                                       Banana Split  ...                                              $8.56
  14                   Reese’s Peanut Butter Cup Sundae  ...                                              $7.67
  15                 Chocolate Chip Cookie Dough Sundae  ...                                              $7.67
  16                               Oreo® Layered Sundae  ...                                              $7.67
  17                          Made with Snickers Sundae  ...                                              $7.67
  18                                   One Scoop Sundae  ...                                              $4.47
  19                                  Two Scoops Sundae  ...                                              $5.75
  20                                Three Scoops Sundae  ...                                              $6.64
  21                                      Candy Topping  ...                                              $1.01
  22                                        Waffle Bowl  ...                                              $1.27
  23                                          Ice Cream  ...                                          Ice Cream
  24                                        Kid’s Scoop  ...                                              $2.80
  25                                       Single Scoop  ...                                              $3.57
  26                                       Double Scoop  ...                                              $5.11
  27                                Regular Waffle Cone  ...                                              $1.27
  28                              Chocolate Waffle Cone  ...                                              $1.91
  29                                  Fancy Waffle Cone  ...                                              $1.91
  30                                          Beverages  ...                                          Beverages
  31                                   Cappuccino Blast  ...                                              $4.72
  32                                   Cappuccino Blast  ...                                              $6.00
  33                                   Cappuccino Blast  ...                                              $7.28
  34                                   Cappuccino Blast  ...                                              $8.56
  35                                   Iced Cappy Blast  ...                                              $4.72
  36                                   Iced Cappy Blast  ...                                              $6.00
  37                                   Iced Cappy Blast  ...                                              $7.28
  38                                   Iced Cappy Blast  ...                                              $8.56
  39       Add a Boost (Cappuccino or Iced Cappy Blast)  ...                                              $0.64
  40                                           Smoothie  ...                                              $4.72
  41                                           Smoothie  ...                                              $6.00
  42                                           Smoothie  ...                                              $7.28
  43                                           Smoothie  ...                                              $8.56
  44                                              Shake  ...                                              $4.72
  45                                              Shake  ...                                              $6.00
  46                                              Shake  ...                                              $7.28
  47                                              Shake  ...                                              $8.56
  48                                    Ice Cream To Go  ...                                    Ice Cream To Go
  49                                         Pre-Packed  ...                                              $7.67
  50                                        Hand-Packed  ...                                              $6.39
  51                                        Hand-Packed  ...                                             $10.23
  52                                        Clown Cones  ...                                              $3.70

  [53 rows x 3 columns]]
  ```