# Scraping tables from website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm new to python and was trying to scrape data from a website. So far, i can successfully scrape the data however the output is given in a linear format instead of the table its pulled from. Could someone give me some pointers on how to get the correct output?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2})
chrome_options.add_argument("-headless")
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options = chrome_options)

today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

date_range = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end=lastMonth, freq='MS')
date_range.strftime("%B/%Y")

date_list = [i.strftime('%B/%Y') for i in date_range]

base_url = "https://www.horseracing.net/tipsters/sky-sports-racing/alex-hammond/"

length = len(date_list)
i = 41 # set to 41 for testing purposes, I didnt want to loop all the tables until i sorted the output. 


while i < length:
    page_url = str(base_url)+""+str(date_list[i])
    chrome.get(page_url)
    EL2 = chrome.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'main-table-container')
    print(EL2.text)
    i += 1
```

Current Output

```
Date
Pos
Tip
Track
Stake
Type
Odds
Result
30th
5th
Clipsham Gold
Yarmouth
1.0 WIN
Nap
9/4
LOST
29th
2nd
Cavendish
Bath
1.0 WIN
Nap
9/4
LOST
28th
2nd
King Of War
Brighton
1.0 WIN
Nap
2/1
LOST
27th
1st
The Vollan
Southwell
1.0 WIN
Nap
11/8
WON
```

Desired Output (all the sites appended into one dataframe, so I can export to an .xlsx)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKLah.png)

Comment: I recommend that looking for youtube tutorials 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTiXxN3bD-Y&list=UUsFz0IGS9qFcwrh7a91juPg&index=32

Comment: Thank you for your response, will give the video a watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733548/7429447) using [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70207528/7429447) from the **This Month's Tips** table within the [website](https://www.horseracing.net/tipsters/sky-sports-racing/alex-hammond) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.horseracing.net/tipsters/sky-sports-racing/alex-hammond/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cookie-accept-button.cookie-button-link"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.close-modal"))).click()
  date = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-left-section']//span[@class='tiping-row-text' and contains(., '/')]")))]
  pose = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-left-section']//div[@class='tiping-row-cell position-cell']//span")))]
  tip = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-left-section']//div[@class='tiping-row-cell position-cell']//following::div[1]/span")))]
  track = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-right-section']//span[text()='Track']//following::span[1]")))]
  stake = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-right-section']//span[text()='Stake']//following::span[1]")))]
  types = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-right-section']//span[text()='Type']//following::span[1]")))]
  odd = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-right-section']//span[text()='Odds']//following::span[1]")))]
  result = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-table-tiping-row data-type-nap']//section[@class='cell-row-right-section']//div[@class='tiping-row-cell mobile-cell-hide']/span")))]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(date, pose, tip, track, stake, types, odd, result)), columns=['Date', 'Pos', 'Tip', 'Track', 'Stake', 'Type', 'Odds', 'Result'])
  print(df)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  import pandas as pd          
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
         Date   Pos               Tip         Track    Stake Type    Odds Result
  0  08/07/22   3rd       Documenting          York  1.0 WIN  Nap    12/1   LOST
  1  07/07/22   4th         Zechariah     Newmarket  1.0 WIN  Nap     9/4   LOST
  2  06/07/22  10th       Lord Cherry      Yarmouth  1.0 WIN  Nap     9/2   LOST
  3  05/07/22   3rd    Landen Calling     Uttoxeter  1.0 WIN  Nap    13/8   LOST
  4  04/07/22    PU  De Barley Basket     Worcester  1.0 WIN  Nap     4/1   LOST
  5  03/07/22   2nd     Caius Marcius  Market Rasen  1.0 WIN  Nap     9/2   LOST
  6  02/07/22   6th          Chairman       Sandown  1.0 WIN  Nap  100/30   LOST
  7  01/07/22   3rd      Rum Cocktail     Doncaster  1.0 WIN  Nap    11/4   LOST
  ```

Comment: Will give this a try tomorrow morning, thank you for the response