# "Benchmark" of different methods to get text extracted

Tags: python, selenium, benchmarking

I´m trying to extract some scraping of a 221x7 table in selenium. Since my first approach takes approx. 3sec, i was wondering, what is the fastest way and best practice at the same moment.

**1st: 3.6sec**

```
table_content = driver_lsx_watchlist.find_elements(By.XPATH, '''//*[@id="page_content"]/div/div/div/div/module/div/table/tbody''')
table_content = table_content[0].text
table_content = table_content.splitlines()
for i in range(0, len(table_content)):
    print(f'{i} {table_content[i]}')
```

**2nd: about 200sec!!!**

```
for row in range(1, 222):
    row_text = ''
    for column in range (1,7):
        xpath = '''//*[@id="page_content"]/div/div/div/div/module/div/table/tbody/tr[''' + str(row) + ''']/td[''' + str(column) + ''']/div'''
        row_text = row_text + driver_lsx_watchlist.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)[0].text
    print(row_text)
```

**3rd: a bit over 4sec**

```
print(driver_lsx_watchlist.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body").text)
```

**4th: 0.2sec**

```
ActionChains(driver_lsx_watchlist)\
    .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
    .send_keys("a")\
    .key_up(Keys.CONTROL)\
    .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
    .send_keys("c")\
    .key_up(Keys.CONTROL)\
    .perform()
```

Since the clipboard seems to be the fastest of all, but renders my pc useless since the clipboard itself is occupied by the process, i wonder what the best practice would be and if i get a proper solution with under 1 second while using the very same pc.

Comment: can you confirm the url where this table resides?

Comment: It is a dynamic table. The content I get via print() is also as expected. The URL is https://www.ls-x.de/de/watchlist The table will be 0 length for you unless you add items to your watch list. I can sample copy/paste some code from my watchlist´s source could if it helps.

Comment: @ngn16920 Unless you add items to your watch list, it appears empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape table within the [webpage](https://www.ls-x.de/de/watchlist) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) for the **`<table>`** element and using [*DataFrame*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70128927/7429447) from [*Pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70165627/7429447) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.ls-x.de/de/watchlist'})
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.accept"))).click()
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='page_content']/div/div/div/div/module/div/table"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df  = pd.read_html(data)
print(df)
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This works like a charm. Still, why is the "selenium only" approach so much slower than adding pandas to the fray?

Comment: @ngn16920 Using Selenium you are dealing with the fully [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) HTML [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). Hence the _`visibility_of_element_located()`_ and it's a part of functional testing. But if you look from performance perspective (only data extraction) Selenium may not be the best fit. Requests module will fit better.