# Empty CSV when writing selenium data

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-chromedriver

I'm making my first experience with Selenium and doing a few tutorials on a well-known video platform. It works quite reliable most of the time. However, I had a problem with a few pages that the CSV is created but no export of the data is made. The CSV is "touched", but it does not export the data that is displayed in a normal print.

Can anyone help me where the problem is with this script?

```
#_*_coding: utf-8_*_


from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import csv
import os

os.chdir("C:\Selenium")
PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://twitter-trends.iamrohit.in/")

try: 
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "panel-body"))
    )
 
    main = (main.text)
 
    f = open('twitter.csv', 'wb')
    print(main, file = f)
    f.close()
    
    #print(main)

except:
    driver.quit()

driver.quit()
```

Python Version 3.7.4, Selenium Versionm 3.141.0, Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging your code you are getting the data correctly.

```
   main = (main.text)
   print(main)
   f = open('twitter.csv', 'wb')
```

So the error is when you are writing to the output file. Replacing your code for

```
main = (main.text)

with open('twitter.txt', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
# Writing data to a file
    file1.writelines(main)
```

will work, if you check the print you have Chinese characters that will make fail the writing in the output file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Did I understand it correctly: It will not work with Chinese characters? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: It will work if you use the option "encoding='utf-8" like i put in my code

Comment: If you want to save your text as csv you will need to make some transformations before, you can read more here.. 
https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/

Comment: Now it worked... I had probably put in a bug on my first try. Perfect, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To scrape the [Twitter Trends - Worldwide](https://twitter-trends.iamrohit.in/) table you can use *DataFrame* from *Python Pandas* and write it to a *csv* file using the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

driver.get("https://twitter-trends.iamrohit.in/")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[text()='Note:']"))))
headers = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "thead > tr > th")))]
ranks = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='twitter-trends']//tbody//tr//descendant::th[1]")))]
topics = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='twitter-trends']//tbody/tr//descendant::th[2]/a")))]
volumes = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='twitter-trends']//tbody/tr//descendant::th[3]")))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(ranks, topics, volumes)), columns=headers)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Data_Files\output_files\twitter.csv', index=False)
driver.quit()
```

CSV Snapshot:

[image: twitter]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Pandas DF.output write to columns (current data is written all to one row or one column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131810/pandas-df-output-write-to-columns-current-data-is-written-all-to-one-row-or-one/70139517#70139517)
- [Selenium: Web-Scraping Historical Data from Coincodex and transform into a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126393/selenium-web-scraping-historical-data-from-coincodex-and-transform-into-a-panda/70128927#70128927)
- [Scraping and writing the table into dataframe shows me TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158178/scraping-and-writing-the-table-into-dataframe-shows-me-typeerror/70160219#70160219)

Comment: This suggestion also works very well! Thank you!

Comment: Tested it on different [Twitter Trends - Worldwide](https://todaytagz.com/twitter-trends/). Works.

Comment: @AdarshKumar Glad to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

> from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
> import Options from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait from
> selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from selenium.webdriver.support
> import expected_conditions as EC import pandas as pd
>
> driver.get("https://twitter-trends.iamrohit.in/")
> driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",
> WebDriverWait(driver,
> 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
> "//b[text()='Note:']")))) headers = [my_elem.text for my_elem in
> WebDriverWait(driver,
> 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
> "thead > tr > th")))] ranks = [my_elem.text for my_elem in
> WebDriverWait(driver,
> 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
> "//table[@id='twitter-trends']//tbody//tr//descendant::th[1](https://trending24.info/united-arab-emirates)")))]
> topics = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver,
> 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
> "//table[@id='twitter-trends']//tbody/tr//descendant::th[2]/a")))]
> volumes = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver,
> 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
> "//table[@id='twitter-trends']//tbody/tr//descendant::th[3]")))] df =
> pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(ranks, topics, volumes)), columns=headers)
> df.to_csv(r'C:\Data_Files\output_files\twitter.csv', index=False)
> driver.quit()
> May this useful [Twitter Trend](https://trending24.info/united-arab-emirates)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32532399)