# How to scrape a dynamic table using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm currently trying to scrape a website for some information and whenever I try to locate elements by their XPath or their css selector, the code returns that it's unable to find such elements. This page is one you have to input a value in a box to generate the table. Here's my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests

path_driver = "C:/Users/CS330584/Documents/Documentos de Defesa da Concorrência/Automatização de Processos/chromedriver.exe"
website = "https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/DAT/DEV-JUR-CON.aspx"
value_search = "999"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver)
driver.get(website)

search_max = driver.find_element_by_name("txtMaiores")
search_max.send_keys(value_search)

btn_consult = driver.find_element_by_class_name("botaoMed")
btn_consult.click()

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="conteudoResult"]/table')
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You need to [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: At which line and step are you stuck? Update the question with the error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

To print table rows you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` with [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945168/access-to-table-objects-on-webpage-using-python-selenium/69947765#69947765) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/DAT/DEV-JUR-CON.aspx")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='txtMaiores']"))).send_keys("999")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.botaoMed").click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.painel tr")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/DAT/DEV-JUR-CON.aspx")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='txtMaiores']"))).send_keys("999")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='botaoMed']").click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='painel']//tr")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Nome CNPJ Fase Administrativa Fase Judicial Em Discussão Judicial Total', 'CAMBARA S/A PROD FLORESTAIS\n96.551.445\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 367.248.250,96\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 367.248.250,96', 'OLVEBRA INDL S/A EM RECUPERAÇÃO JUDICIAL\n89.028.575\nR$ 8.962.272,86\nR$ 324.574.986,58\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 333.537.259,44', 'RIO GRANDE ENERGIA S/A\n02.016.439\nR$ 9.016,50\nR$ 243.391.712,69\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 243.400.729,19', 'VOGES METALURGIA LTDA MASSA FALIDA\n04.654.447\nR$ 1.558,24\nR$ 218.714.320,27\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 218.715.878,51', 'MANZOLI S A COM E IND\n92.696.517\nR$ 720.512,19\nR$ 215.632.218,93\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 216.352.731,12', 'USINAS SID DE MINAS GERAIS S A USIMINAS\n60.894.730\nR$ 7.698.314,84\nR$ 168.932.566,66\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 176.630.881,50', 'LATICINIOS BOM GOSTO S A\n94.679.479\nR$ 10.939,44\nR$ 161.384.861,10\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 161.395.800,54', 'SANTAMATE IND E COM LTDA\n01.706.643\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 147.883.431,15\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 147.883.431,15', 'CRYSALIS SEMPRE MIO IND E COM DE CALCADOS LTDA\n87.377.305\nR$ 506,09\nR$ 135.262.417,61\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 135.262.923,70', 'FRIG MARIENSE LTDA\n89.762.249\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 133.335.328,50\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 133.335.328,50', 'TRORION GAUCHA INDL DE POLIURETANOS LTDA\n92.702.562\nR$ 127.225.154,18\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 127.225.154,18', 'MINAS ZINCO IND E COM LTDA\n05.074.567\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 119.697.515,64\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 119.697.515,64', 'UGHINI S A IND E COM\n97.577.209\nR$ 1.657.723,95\nR$ 113.151.368,56\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 114.809.092,51', 'ITABA IND DE TABACO BRASILEIRA LTDA\n02.750.676\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 113.689.148,57\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 113.689.148,57', 'TRANSPA TEGON VALENTI S/A\n87.550.281\nR$ 1.541.514,93\nR$ 109.655.511,09\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 111.197.026,02', 'COTRIJUI COOP AGROPEC & INDL LIQUI JUDICIAL\n90.726.506\nR$ 8.857.337,36\nR$ 98.744.455,58\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 107.601.792,94', ... 'UNIGRAN CEREAIS LTDA\n01.334.369\nR$ 133.484,03\nR$ 6.110.537,94\nR$ 0,00\nR$ 6.244.021,97']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a wait action, which will wait for some time until/if your xpath appears:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def wait_until_xpath(driver, xpath: str, timeout: float = 0.5 ):
    """
    Wait for some time until an element is visible.
    
    Args:
      driver: selenium webdriver
      xpath: string repr of an xpath
      timeout: how many seconds before returning None
    """
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)\
            .until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, xpath)
             ))
        return element
except TimeoutException:
    return None
```

Use as follows:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="conteudoResult"]/table'
table = wait_until_xpath(driver, xpath, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should induce explicit wait which is driven by WebDriverWait in Selenium Automation.

So your effective code block would be :

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

website = "https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/DAT/DEV-JUR-CON.aspx"
value_search = "999"

driver.get(website)

search_max = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "txtMaiores")))
search_max.send_keys(value_search)

btn_consult = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "botaoMed")))
btn_consult.click()

table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='conteudoResult']/table")))
entire_text = table.get_attribute('innerText')
print(entire_text)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
CAMBARA S/A PROD FLORESTAIS 96.551.445 R$ 0,00 R$ 367.248.250,96 R$ 0,00 R$ 367.248.250,96 

OLVEBRA INDL S/A EM RECUPERAÇÃO JUDICIAL 89.028.575 R$ 8.962.272,86 R$ 324.574.986,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 333.537.259,44 

RIO GRANDE ENERGIA S/A 02.016.439 R$ 9.016,50 R$ 243.391.712,69 R$ 0,00 R$ 243.400.729,19 

VOGES METALURGIA LTDA MASSA FALIDA 04.654.447 R$ 1.558,24 R$ 218.714.320,27 R$ 0,00 R$ 218.715.878,51 

MANZOLI S A COM E IND 92.696.517 R$ 720.512,19 R$ 215.632.218,93 R$ 0,00 R$ 216.352.731,12 

USINAS SID DE MINAS GERAIS S A USIMINAS 60.894.730 R$ 7.698.314,84 R$ 168.932.566,66 R$ 0,00 R$ 176.630.881,50 

LATICINIOS BOM GOSTO S A 94.679.479 R$ 10.939,44 R$ 161.384.861,10 R$ 0,00 R$ 161.395.800,54 

SANTAMATE IND E COM LTDA 01.706.643 R$ 0,00 R$ 147.883.431,15 R$ 0,00 R$ 147.883.431,15 

CRYSALIS SEMPRE MIO IND E COM DE CALCADOS LTDA 87.377.305 R$ 506,09 R$ 135.262.417,61 R$ 0,00 R$ 135.262.923,70 

FRIG MARIENSE LTDA 89.762.249 R$ 0,00 R$ 133.335.328,50 R$ 0,00 R$ 133.335.328,50 

TRORION GAUCHA INDL DE POLIURETANOS LTDA 92.702.562 R$ 127.225.154,18 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 127.225.154,18 

MINAS ZINCO IND E COM LTDA 05.074.567 R$ 0,00 R$ 119.697.515,64 R$ 0,00 R$ 119.697.515,64 

UGHINI S A IND E COM 97.577.209 R$ 1.657.723,95 R$ 113.151.368,56 R$ 0,00 R$ 114.809.092,51 

ITABA IND DE TABACO BRASILEIRA LTDA 02.750.676 R$ 0,00 R$ 113.689.148,57 R$ 0,00 R$ 113.689.148,57 

TRANSPA TEGON VALENTI S/A 87.550.281 R$ 1.541.514,93 R$ 109.655.511,09 R$ 0,00 R$ 111.197.026,02 

COTRIJUI COOP AGROPEC & INDL LIQUI JUDICIAL 90.726.506 R$ 8.857.337,36 R$ 98.744.455,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 107.601.792,94 

FRIG TRES C S/A 91.448.076 R$ 41.624.220,70 R$ 59.152.944,40 R$ 0,00 R$ 100.777.165,10 

VIGISUL ZELADORIA LTDA 88.649.488 R$ 0,00 R$ 100.143.128,77 R$ 0,00 R$ 100.143.128,77 

C & P IND DE LATICINIOS LTDA 09.354.227 R$ 7.051.050,40 R$ 91.914.609,22 R$ 0,00 R$ 98.965.659,62 

DIPLOMATA S/A INDL E COML MASSA FALIDA 01.243.305 R$ 0,00 R$ 97.141.284,86 R$ 0,00 R$ 97.141.284,86 

TRES PORTOS S/A IND DE PAPEL 89.723.852 R$ 945,04 R$ 93.490.046,39 R$ 0,00 R$ 93.490.991,43 

ORTOTECH S A 90.261.199 R$ 0,00 R$ 89.830.357,56 R$ 0,00 R$ 89.830.357,56 

AGRICAPE S/A PROD ALIMENTARES 87.475.240 R$ 15.026.909,12 R$ 74.652.875,92 R$ 0,00 R$ 89.679.785,04 

COML DE ELETRODOMESTICOS PEDRO OBINO JUNIOR SA 87.396.172 R$ 5.491.579,91 R$ 83.376.372,69 R$ 0,00 R$ 88.867.952,60 

CIA GERAL DE INDUSTRIAS 92.659.325 R$ 59.065.605,28 R$ 24.447.667,32 R$ 0,00 R$ 83.513.272,60 

OI S/A EM RECUPERACAO JUDICIAL 76.535.764 R$ 0,00 R$ 83.052.637,87 R$ 0,00 R$ 83.052.637,87 

PSA INDL DE PAPEL S/A 96.735.907 R$ 10.663.318,26 R$ 72.019.244,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 82.682.562,50 

ALUMINIO ROYAL S/A 92.690.122 R$ 1.089.574,74 R$ 81.185.330,21 R$ 0,00 R$ 82.274.904,95 

PAVIOLI S/A EM RECUPERAçãO JUDICIAL 92.878.180 R$ 1.585.408,25 R$ 80.436.428,88 R$ 0,00 R$ 82.021.837,13 

SANTA RITA COM IND E REPR LTDA 04.913.056 R$ 0,00 R$ 80.240.350,11 R$ 0,00 R$ 80.240.350,11 

L T DISTRIB ATACADISTA LTDA 04.001.637 R$ 0,00 R$ 79.043.553,16 R$ 0,00 R$ 79.043.553,16 

GLOBAL VILLAGE TELECOM S/A 03.420.926 R$ 0,00 R$ 77.835.791,09 R$ 0,00 R$ 77.835.791,09 

AL DISTRIB DE MEDICAMENTOS LTDA 95.623.831 R$ 0,00 R$ 75.321.394,16 R$ 0,00 R$ 75.321.394,16 

MURARO & CIA LTDA 89.962.781 R$ 0,00 R$ 74.265.810,22 R$ 0,00 R$ 74.265.810,22 

JOLLY IND DE CALCADOS LTDA 88.175.468 R$ 0,00 R$ 73.342.189,26 R$ 0,00 R$ 73.342.189,26 

ITM S/A IND DE TECNOLOGIAS MEDICAS 88.303.433 R$ 0,00 R$ 72.466.389,04 R$ 0,00 R$ 72.466.389,04 

METALACS RS COM DE METAIS LTDA 03.596.347 R$ 7.709.875,38 R$ 64.510.707,25 R$ 0,00 R$ 72.220.582,63 

PLUMA CONFORTO E TURISMO S/A 76.530.278 R$ 138.775,06 R$ 70.419.317,39 R$ 0,00 R$ 70.558.092,45 

JAYME WAINBERG S A IND E COM DE ENXOVAIS 92.732.338 R$ 7.752,34 R$ 69.927.057,92 R$ 0,00 R$ 69.934.810,26 

CERVEJARIA RIOGR LTDA 05.766.005 R$ 2.251,91 R$ 69.744.808,03 R$ 0,00 R$ 69.747.059,94 

CIAX COM DE PETROLEO LTDA 01.729.209 R$ 0,00 R$ 69.164.231,61 R$ 0,00 R$ 69.164.231,61 

COOP VITI VINICOLA POMPEIA LTDA 87.547.980 R$ 58.563.272,61 R$ 9.563.519,20 R$ 0,00 R$ 68.126.791,81 

PL FUNDICAO E SERVS LTDA 03.333.402 R$ 2.892,14 R$ 66.909.279,87 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.912.172,01 

FAB CYRILLA DE BEBIDAS LTDA 95.591.657 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.901.859,47 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.901.859,47 

MASSA FALIDA DE METALCORTE FUNDICAO LTDA 03.273.282 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.886.540,01 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.886.540,01 

VACCHI S/A IND E COM 92.761.618 R$ 39.431,70 R$ 66.678.637,15 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.718.068,85 

COOP ARRZ EXTREMO SUL LTDA 92.195.692 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.504.189,03 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.504.189,03 

CALCADOS RUTHI LTDA 97.751.366 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.326.756,39 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.326.756,39 

FRIG BASSANENSE S/A 91.614.131 R$ 62.911.785,28 R$ 3.371.536,76 R$ 0,00 R$ 66.283.322,04 

BORDACO S/A COM E IND 47.107.800 R$ 0,00 R$ 64.044.614,04 R$ 0,00 R$ 64.044.614,04 

POSTES MARIANI IND E COM LTDA 87.284.261 R$ 105.078,46 R$ 63.765.009,86 R$ 0,00 R$ 63.870.088,32 

MANHATTAN DISTRIB DE PETROLEO LTDA 01.215.869 R$ 0,00 R$ 63.151.495,02 R$ 0,00 R$ 63.151.495,02 

TRADENER LTDA 02.691.745 R$ 0,00 R$ 63.093.047,44 R$ 0,00 R$ 63.093.047,44 

DHB COMPONENTES AUTOMOTIVOS S/A 89.734.537 R$ 12.528,64 R$ 62.997.429,23 R$ 0,00 R$ 63.009.957,87 

FULLER S/A 95.423.935 R$ 28.128.937,58 R$ 34.074.131,90 R$ 0,00 R$ 62.203.069,48 

PETROBOM DISTRIB DE PETROLEO S/A 04.042.015 R$ 0,00 R$ 61.494.680,37 R$ 0,00 R$ 61.494.680,37 

CALCADOS VERA CRUZ LTDA 97.748.891 R$ 1.312.896,23 R$ 59.708.270,96 R$ 0,00 R$ 61.021.167,19 

LUPATECH S A 89.463.822 R$ 0,00 R$ 60.972.365,93 R$ 0,00 R$ 60.972.365,93 

IND E COM DE CONFEC SOBREMONTE LTDA 93.327.104 R$ 1.764,08 R$ 60.559.461,13 R$ 0,00 R$ 60.561.225,21 

COML E INDL DE FERRO E ACO LTDA 08.195.406 R$ 17.720.996,22 R$ 42.073.526,29 R$ 0,00 R$ 59.794.522,51 

MORSCHEL & MORSCHEL LTDA 87.357.794 R$ 0,00 R$ 58.076.527,20 R$ 0,00 R$ 58.076.527,20 

MISTER BRASIL COM IMPORTACAO E EXPORTACAO LTDA 91.518.571 R$ 0,00 R$ 55.809.520,85 R$ 0,00 R$ 55.809.520,85 

CBL CIA BRASILEIRA DE LACTEOS 08.886.448 R$ 0,00 R$ 55.568.852,56 R$ 0,00 R$ 55.568.852,56 

COOP TRITICOLA ERECHIM COTREL EM LIQUIDAÇAO 89.424.824 R$ 8.627,56 R$ 55.155.819,27 R$ 0,00 R$ 55.164.446,83 

CALCADOS CATLEIA LTDA 88.061.262 R$ 309.382,59 R$ 54.626.544,55 R$ 0,00 R$ 54.935.927,14 

TRANSPA STELING LTDA 89.207.211 R$ 2.469.796,70 R$ 52.395.495,11 R$ 0,00 R$ 54.865.291,81 

J H SANTOS S/A COM E IND 92.754.191 R$ 43.478.162,81 R$ 10.062.992,89 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.541.155,70 

ZENGLEIN IND E COM DE CALCADOS EIRELI 91.681.973 R$ 10.540.621,67 R$ 42.834.790,06 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.375.411,73 

CEVENSUL CENTRAL DE VENDAS DO SUL 91.834.788 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 

NEPAR NEGOCIOS ADM E PARTICIPACOES LTDA 02.109.540 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 

INDL BOITUVA DE BEBIDAS S A 91.669.333 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 

EMPRESA DE MINERACAO NEVADA LTDA 92.395.862 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 

JOALPAR HOLDING S A 04.712.298 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 53.200.891,24 

WMS SUPERMERCADOS DO BRASIL LTDA 93.209.765 R$ 10.223.330,77 R$ 42.346.902,09 R$ 0,00 R$ 52.570.232,86 

CURTUME FRIDOLINO RITTER LTDA 91.586.594 R$ 0,00 R$ 52.248.076,28 R$ 0,00 R$ 52.248.076,28 

MADEF S/A IND E COM 92.696.418 R$ 1.751.192,46 R$ 49.696.388,30 R$ 0,00 R$ 51.447.580,76 

COOP REG CASTILHENSE DE CARNES E DERIV LTDA 91.021.782 R$ 4.370.085,40 R$ 45.596.223,97 R$ 0,00 R$ 49.966.309,37 

RENATO MURARO 03.648.377 R$ 0,00 R$ 49.919.068,49 R$ 0,00 R$ 49.919.068,49 

MUSA CALCADOS LTDA 97.276.125 R$ 0,00 R$ 49.805.158,80 R$ 0,00 R$ 49.805.158,80 

NOVAPELLI IND COM IMPORTACAO E EXPORTACAO LTDA 00.121.821 R$ 5.572.765,89 R$ 43.528.732,57 R$ 0,00 R$ 49.101.498,46 

LIDER ALIMENTOS DO BRASIL S/A 80.823.396 R$ 0,00 R$ 48.583.147,36 R$ 0,00 R$ 48.583.147,36 

IND DE PROD ALIMENTICIOS INSTANTANEOS LTDA 97.754.063 R$ 0,00 R$ 48.298.728,75 R$ 0,00 R$ 48.298.728,75 

DIEMENTZ COM DE ELETROMOVEIS LTDA 03.880.277 R$ 476.689,89 R$ 47.613.245,91 R$ 0,00 R$ 48.089.935,80 

FRIVALE S/A FRIG 87.365.839 R$ 0,00 R$ 47.994.270,23 R$ 0,00 R$ 47.994.270,23 

COOP AGRO PEC ALTO URUGUAI LTDA COTRIMAIO 98.042.120 R$ 453.631,35 R$ 47.098.535,09 R$ 0,00 R$ 47.552.166,44 

RODOV MICHELON LTDA 88.619.929 R$ 89.030,48 R$ 47.284.114,37 R$ 0,00 R$ 47.373.144,85 

TOP IND E COM DE ALIMENTOS LTDA 04.437.765 R$ 0,00 R$ 47.174.583,99 R$ 0,00 R$ 47.174.583,99 

AGROINDUSTRIAL AGROVEN LTDA 89.933.428 R$ 15.336.633,70 R$ 31.362.798,28 R$ 0,00 R$ 46.699.431,98 

ALI MUHD SAID YUSUF BAKLIZI 90.099.540 R$ 0,00 R$ 45.972.957,36 R$ 0,00 R$ 45.972.957,36 

CIBRATAR ENGENHARIA LTDA 87.333.340 R$ 0,00 R$ 45.528.992,81 R$ 0,00 R$ 45.528.992,81 

CENTRAL DISTRIBUICAO DE ALIMENTOS LTDA 89.738.553 R$ 2.229,80 R$ 45.413.959,25 R$ 0,00 R$ 45.416.189,05 

IND DE LATICINIOS BG ERECHIM LTDA 09.632.645 R$ 0,00 R$ 44.559.607,45 R$ 0,00 R$ 44.559.607,45 

BRENOLD GROUP S A 05.808.211 R$ 0,00 R$ 44.210.106,71 R$ 0,00 R$ 44.210.106,71 

LUNDGREN IRMAOS TEC S/A 07.209.612 R$ 0,00 R$ 44.059.992,98 R$ 0,00 R$ 44.059.992,98 

ARCELORMITTAL BRASIL S.A. 17.469.701 R$ 0,00 R$ 43.956.886,78 R$ 0,00 R$ 43.956.886,78 

MASSA FALIDA DE DROGARIA MAIS ECONOMICA S A 94.296.175 R$ 11.626,30 R$ 43.441.162,53 R$ 0,00 R$ 43.452.788,83 

COOP RUR ALEGRETENSE LTDA 87.118.931 R$ 0,00 R$ 43.366.930,21 R$ 0,00 R$ 43.366.930,21 

RODMASTER COM DE BATERIAS LTDA 87.960.639 R$ 42.652.928,97 R$ 45.025,69 R$ 0,00 R$ 42.697.954,66 

CALCADOS SIMPATIA LTDA 97.749.188 R$ 0,00 R$ 42.055.718,49 R$ 0,00 R$ 42.055.718,49 

MERIBA AGUAS MINERAIS LTDA 07.882.270 R$ 5.560,42 R$ 41.873.508,06 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.879.068,48 

CIA INDL RIO GUAHYBA 92.779.438 R$ 553.643,89 R$ 41.179.709,39 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.733.353,28 

PIETROBON & CIA LTDA 97.580.260 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.361.497,02 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.361.497,02 

NAMAH EMPREEND E PARTICIPACOES S A 10.537.021 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 

MENPAR ADM E PARTICIPACOES LTDA 08.645.036 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 

LATICINIOS CEDRENSE LTDA 81.783.359 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 

LBR LACTEOS BRASIL SA 02.341.881 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 

SAGA INDL LTDA 05.271.908 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.241.008,58 

BELSUL IND E COM DE MATERIAS PRIMAS LTDA 92.670.173 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.239.016,28 R$ 0,00 R$ 41.239.016,28 

CALCADOS MONTSENY LTDA 97.755.953 R$ 0,00 R$ 40.787.579,03 R$ 0,00 R$ 40.787.579,03 

VECTOR IND DE PROD METALURGICOS LTDA 03.018.339 R$ 15.819.731,38 R$ 24.519.360,80 R$ 0,00 R$ 40.339.092,18 

FOCOFARMA DISTRIB DE MEDIC EIRELI 11.758.853 R$ 1.379.083,06 R$ 38.449.605,46 R$ 0,00 R$ 39.828.688,52 

MEDICOUROS COM DE COUROS LTDA 97.093.660 R$ 2.522.424,19 R$ 36.757.994,32 R$ 0,00 R$ 39.280.418,51 

SAUL SZOLEM SZWARCBERG ZAK 89.133.623 R$ 5.951.140,69 R$ 33.273.489,86 R$ 0,00 R$ 39.224.630,55 

COOP TRITICOLA DE GETULIO VARGAS LTDA 90.155.953 R$ 4.244,15 R$ 39.197.434,38 R$ 0,00 R$ 39.201.678,53 

OFF ROAD S CALCADOS LTDA 90.849.324 R$ 27.352.100,60 R$ 11.634.670,36 R$ 0,00 R$ 38.986.770,96 

CASA LYRA COM E IMP LTDA 92.751.122 R$ 0,00 R$ 38.856.979,94 R$ 0,00 R$ 38.856.979,94 

GENERAL MEAT FOOD EXP E IMP LTDA 02.298.243 R$ 1.985.696,65 R$ 36.565.662,32 R$ 0,00 R$ 38.551.358,97 

VINICOLA MURARO LTDA 89.965.800 R$ 0,00 R$ 36.586.309,94 R$ 0,00 R$ 36.586.309,94 

MORGANTI S/A IND E COM 90.021.726 R$ 36.207.206,49 R$ 160.183,70 R$ 0,00 R$ 36.367.390,19 

MINERACAO ARROIO BONITO LTDA 07.337.486 R$ 574.751,81 R$ 35.692.026,30 R$ 0,00 R$ 36.266.778,11 

CALCADOS GUILHERME LUDWIG S/A 87.226.619 R$ 35.876.046,82 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 35.876.046,82 

NACIONAL S A IND COM E DISTR DE BEBIDAS 88.347.463 R$ 0,00 R$ 35.830.175,33 R$ 0,00 R$ 35.830.175,33 

CELEIRO IMP E EXP DE CEREAIS LTDA 00.819.675 R$ 0,00 R$ 35.784.176,36 R$ 0,00 R$ 35.784.176,36 

COOP VITIVINICOLA FORQUETA LTDA 88.613.278 R$ 553.108,75 R$ 35.063.344,68 R$ 0,00 R$ 35.616.453,43 

CIA NACIONAL DE BEBIDAS NOBRES 45.426.798 R$ 58.923,29 R$ 35.098.861,06 R$ 0,00 R$ 35.157.784,35 

EXCELLENT PLASTICOS COM DE EMBALAGENS EIRELI 17.027.599 R$ 17.453.878,88 R$ 17.441.426,43 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.895.305,31 

DISTRIB DE PNEUS ALEGRETE LTDA 16.639.904 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.692.967,40 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.692.967,40 

REAL TABACOS LTDA 04.923.986 R$ 3.349,56 R$ 34.539.070,50 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.542.420,06 

POP MAN IND E COM DE CONFEC LTDA 00.554.541 R$ 34.523.571,01 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.523.571,01 

BELLA GRES IND DE CERAMICA LTDA 94.778.446 R$ 3.037,12 R$ 34.511.201,95 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.514.239,07 

PINUS MADEIRAS E COMPENSADOS LTDA 93.192.961 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.508.675,29 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.508.675,29 

INDL HAHN FERRABRAZ S/A 88.941.125 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.304.611,48 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.304.611,48 

M C SILVA AGRO INDL DE CARNES LTDA 10.470.426 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.302.187,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.302.187,58 

DELLA NONNA PROD ALIMENT LTDA 90.384.801 R$ 1.870.409,83 R$ 32.335.533,78 R$ 0,00 R$ 34.205.943,61 

SULCHEM PLASTICOS S/A 22.259.718 R$ 17.453.878,88 R$ 16.189.452,56 R$ 0,00 R$ 33.643.331,44 

SOC PROD TONDING LTDA 92.779.404 R$ 0,00 R$ 33.104.701,90 R$ 0,00 R$ 33.104.701,90 

PANTI PATI MODAS E ACESSORIOS LTDA 94.675.089 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.964.403,81 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.964.403,81 

CAPITAL COM DE CIGARROS LTDA 08.870.114 R$ 2.459,82 R$ 32.923.425,63 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.925.885,45 

TECNOSONO IND DE ESPUMAS E COLCHOES LTDA 90.469.800 R$ 10.478.482,92 R$ 22.303.978,90 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.782.461,82 

REDESPORTE S/A 92.715.606 R$ 21.115.464,93 R$ 11.428.212,92 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.543.677,85 

AGUILA COMERCIO DE MALHAS LTDA 04.315.340 R$ 1.471.139,25 R$ 30.958.655,66 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.429.794,91 

KAERCHER & KAERCHER LTDA 07.782.416 R$ 5.836,09 R$ 32.149.355,97 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.155.192,06 

VIER IND E COM DO MATE LTDA 87.689.303 R$ 4.947,85 R$ 32.089.283,31 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.094.231,16 

DAM DISTRIB DE METAIS LTDA 92.690.254 R$ 6.369.192,59 R$ 25.716.664,85 R$ 0,00 R$ 32.085.857,44 

LATICINIO SEBERI LTDA EM RECUPERACAO JUDICIAL 05.490.835 R$ 4.908.637,22 R$ 26.957.357,41 R$ 0,00 R$ 31.865.994,63 

MADEZORZI S/A 88.610.159 R$ 274.994,58 R$ 31.170.455,12 R$ 0,00 R$ 31.445.449,70 

IND DE CALCADOS FLAMA LTDA 97.275.945 R$ 0,00 R$ 31.384.495,32 R$ 0,00 R$ 31.384.495,32 

THV COM DO VEST LTDA 92.659.416 R$ 23.297,31 R$ 30.995.091,53 R$ 0,00 R$ 31.018.388,84 

IRMAOS PETROLL & CIA LTDA 96.735.790 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.926.230,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.926.230,58 

MOVELPAR IND COM E IMPORTACAO LTDA 91.032.383 R$ 3.231.938,60 R$ 27.405.438,05 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.637.376,65 

SANTALUCIA ALIMENTOS LTDA 90.471.798 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.486.169,16 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.486.169,16 

IND DE BEBIDAS CELINA LTDA 98.658.834 R$ 20.927.714,98 R$ 9.367.181,59 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.294.896,57 

BROCHIER CALCADOS LTDA 91.674.275 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.289.632,80 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.289.632,80 

IND DE POSTES INDASUL LTDA 03.791.069 R$ 28.767,01 R$ 30.078.351,73 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.107.118,74 

IRMAOS THONNIGS LTDA 88.454.582 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.067.741,71 R$ 0,00 R$ 30.067.741,71 

THONART MOV VERGADOS S/A 92.661.958 R$ 605.138,10 R$ 29.335.032,04 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.940.170,14 

LOJAS VOLPATO LTDA - EM RECUPERACAO JUDICIAL 88.957.659 R$ 5.010.694,96 R$ 24.864.332,84 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.875.027,80 

FICET IND E COM DE CIGARROS E IMP E EXP LTDA 02.421.127 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.844.017,37 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.844.017,37 

ARAFERTIL COM E DISTRIB DE CIGARROS LTDA 88.274.824 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.688.992,55 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.688.992,55 

BRISA EMBALAGENS LTDA 91.522.748 R$ 8.676.364,24 R$ 20.824.068,79 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.500.433,03 

SIMONE CLER SILVA EMERICK 08.463.560 R$ 10.719,18 R$ 29.478.145,32 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.488.864,50 

CALCADOS JUCARA LTDA 88.059.662 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.045.279,59 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.045.279,59 

TLP DISCOS LTDA 91.744.060 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.029.380,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 29.029.380,24 

TRANSIT DO BRASIL LTDA 02.868.267 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.870.141,52 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.870.141,52 

COML DE FUMOS A L LTDA 86.761.665 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.816.737,58 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.816.737,58 

JVS FRIG E COM DE CARNES LTDA ME 03.303.497 R$ 5.882.524,64 R$ 22.910.397,71 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.792.922,35 

TRATHO METAL QUIMICA LTDA 18.001.764 R$ 28.759.197,12 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.759.197,12 

PROLABHO DISTRIB DE PROD PARA SAUDE LTDA 73.993.875 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.704.756,44 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.704.756,44 

DROGARIA CAPILE LTDA 92.786.037 R$ 417.548,92 R$ 28.094.419,72 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.511.968,64 

JOAO BATISTA DE SOUZA 93.465.474 R$ 28.290.647,02 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.290.647,02 

CAPRI INDL LTDA 01.580.849 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.251.042,03 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.251.042,03 

QUINTA DO VALE ALIMENTOS LTDA 00.218.077 R$ 16.804.957,63 R$ 11.300.963,79 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.105.921,42 

FRIG RIO SUL LTDA 89.411.094 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.095.847,39 R$ 0,00 R$ 28.095.847,39 

KTEX IND TEXTIL EIRELI ME 07.642.180 R$ 5.785,84 R$ 27.763.402,45 R$ 0,00 R$ 27.769.188,29 

PROTELYNE CALCADOS DE SEGURANCA LTDA 72.203.524 R$ 5.239,46 R$ 27.286.163,43 R$ 0,00 R$ 27.291.402,89 

MKJ IMP & COM LTDA 03.403.405 R$ 0,00 R$ 27.283.753,38 R$ 0,00 R$ 27.283.753,38 

FIGUERAS S/A 92.779.172 R$ 26.996.364,24 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.996.364,24 

INDS IBIRUBENSE S/A 90.657.164 R$ 41.617,15 R$ 26.903.862,92 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.945.480,07 

EURO TELHAS IND E COM LTDA 02.290.876 R$ 1.170.903,29 R$ 25.481.283,84 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.652.187,13 

DISTRIB HORBICENTER EIRELI 04.535.566 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.639.928,04 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.639.928,04 

ROADLINE DO BRASIL LTDA 03.215.007 R$ 3.817.176,55 R$ 22.633.376,54 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.450.553,09 

V R N KLAUCK EIRELI 09.181.944 R$ 12.813.706,27 R$ 13.600.050,31 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.413.756,58 

GLOBO INOX EQUIP INDUSTRIAIS LTDA 92.882.950 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.392.740,60 R$ 0,00 R$ 26.392.740,60 

CHOCOLATE DO PARKE EIRELI 91.385.310 R$ 12.099,83 R$ 25.970.142,96 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.982.242,79 

FIBRA S/A IND E COM 91.677.047 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.927.071,71 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.927.071,71 

TRES VALES IND COM DE PESCADOS LTDA REC JUD 02.012.525 R$ 2.063,78 R$ 25.872.465,03 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.874.528,81 

CROMA INDS ALIMENTARES S/A 92.681.766 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.832.517,39 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.832.517,39 

COML DE MAQ NORDESTE LTDA 87.821.005 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.821.591,31 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.821.591,31 

MATHEUS VICENZO CALCADOS LTDA 92.315.381 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.681.024,25 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.681.024,25 

LEV E MONTE IND COM E SERVS PARA MOV LTDA 02.561.384 R$ 20.682,65 R$ 25.490.054,40 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.510.737,05 

LUMINARIAS DAVAL IND E COM LTDA 93.797.744 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.438.386,25 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.438.386,25 

EFEGE ARMAZ TRANSP CARGAS E ADM DE BENS LTDA 94.141.256 R$ 1.381,13 R$ 25.419.666,98 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.421.048,11 

SHEIK S/A IND E COM 46.849.196 R$ 18.665.395,66 R$ 6.629.364,21 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.294.759,87 

COOP AGROPEC COOPSUL LTDA 06.063.610 R$ 24.726.980,96 R$ 511.194,80 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.238.175,76 

CAVASOTTO COM DE TEC LTDA 91.667.741 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.188.811,75 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.188.811,75 

EMPRESA DE TRANSPS WILSON LTDA 89.849.681 R$ 3.897.235,58 R$ 21.271.053,31 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.168.288,89 

JOAO HOPPE INDL S/A 92.778.596 R$ 6.043.653,08 R$ 19.064.627,48 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.108.280,56 

VINHEDOS REFEICOES COLETIVAS LTDA 93.805.018 R$ 9.427,33 R$ 25.073.545,21 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.082.972,54 

TRANSUNI TRANSPORTES ESPECIAIS LTDA 90.390.980 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.066.797,71 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.066.797,71 

NIQUELFER COM DE METAIS LTDA 54.798.350 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.019.498,79 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.019.498,79 

CORDOARIA SAO LEOPOLDO S/A 96.734.850 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.005.217,39 R$ 0,00 R$ 25.005.217,39 

FRIG RIO GUAIBA LTDA 92.160.282 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.973.168,91 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.973.168,91 

OLIVERIO MINERACAO DE CAULIM LTDA 95.109.104 R$ 23.850.243,51 R$ 970.680,95 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.820.924,46 

SALTOS SANDENSE LTDA 87.377.602 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.714.226,04 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.714.226,04 

DIFAR COM E REPR LTDA 90.059.163 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.669.817,36 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.669.817,36 

VRS IND DE LATICINIOS LTDA 03.520.800 R$ 4.644,25 R$ 24.662.656,99 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.667.301,24 

JULIO CESAR DA CUNHA LUZ 02.812.617 R$ 7.963.597,33 R$ 16.647.384,29 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.610.981,62 

IMDEPA ROLAMENTOS IMP E COM LTDA 88.613.922 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.569.237,60 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.569.237,60 

INCOSIL IND DE INJETADOS PLASTICOS LTDA 94.330.834 R$ 24.304.377,52 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.304.377,52 

PROD ALIMENTICIOS CORSETTI S/A INDUSTRIA E COM 88.610.282 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.301.531,25 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.301.531,25 

BORRACHAS VIPAL S A 87.870.952 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.236.628,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.236.628,00 

SUL AMERICAN TRADE COM IMP E EXP LTDA 97.381.487 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.078.523,36 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.078.523,36 

FERRAO SANCHI & CIA LTDA 02.461.336 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.072.448,91 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.072.448,91 

PILOT IND E COM DE CALCADOS LTDA 94.637.378 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.011.533,85 R$ 0,00 R$ 24.011.533,85 

ALIMIX RIO PROD ALIMENT LTDA 15.283.446 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.942.365,32 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.942.365,32 

KRONE IND MECANICA LTDA 90.571.647 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.865.977,51 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.865.977,51 

TRANSAZUL IND E COM DE CEREAIS LTDA 88.345.558 R$ 730.764,30 R$ 23.010.143,23 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.740.907,53 

MED EXPRESS COM DE MEDIC E MAT MED HOSP LTDA 01.818.405 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.662.602,31 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.662.602,31 

MONTREALFARMA DISTRIB DE MEDIC LTDA 05.220.169 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.659.750,52 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.659.750,52 

BKP COM DE BEBIDAS LTDA 00.391.638 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.560.856,10 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.560.856,10 

ALBERTO ANDRE KAERCHER 02.999.180 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.474.720,43 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.474.720,43 

FRIG CAXIENSE LTDA 01.593.913 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.450.436,73 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.450.436,73 

IMPERIAL ABSOLUT IND BRAS DE COLCHOES LTDA 01.075.114 R$ 6.056,68 R$ 23.402.435,61 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.408.492,29 

HIDRANCE COSMETICOS EIRELI EPP 03.992.704 R$ 9.885.322,24 R$ 13.476.504,93 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.361.827,17 

BERMATEX COM IMP TEXTIL LTDA 01.631.355 R$ 4.969.057,73 R$ 18.351.751,23 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.320.808,96 

MOBIUS HEALTH SA 21.609.366 R$ 1.253,28 R$ 23.207.803,37 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.209.056,65 

ALCOOL PORTO XAVIER S/A 90.177.726 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.089.768,94 R$ 0,00 R$ 23.089.768,94 

ENXUTA S/A 88.611.975 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.984.331,99 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.984.331,99 

ICONE COML EIRELI 89.907.950 R$ 701.011,25 R$ 22.272.400,51 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.973.411,76 

GGTC IMP EXP E COM DE GRAOS LTDA 14.128.073 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.962.230,17 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.962.230,17 

CONTINENTAL IMPRA E EXPRA LTDA 94.015.468 R$ 11.189.755,66 R$ 11.574.269,26 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.764.024,92 

POLO WEAR PLATINUM OUTLET COM DE CONFEC LTDA 17.717.658 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.559.961,21 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.559.961,21 

PINHATTI IMP E EXP LTDA 87.338.901 R$ 21.985.473,02 R$ 324.343,15 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.309.816,17 

WR TEXTIL IND E COM LTDA 87.525.010 R$ 5.974.822,57 R$ 16.254.635,35 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.229.457,92 

RGFH ENGENHARIA LTDA 02.882.162 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.224.440,66 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.224.440,66 

MICROCOM DO BRASIL LTDA 68.846.336 R$ 287.492,56 R$ 21.906.582,63 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.194.075,19 

L F M METALURGICA SA 92.780.352 R$ 4.551.186,03 R$ 17.591.051,78 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.142.237,81 

FEDRIZZI & CIA LTDA 88.611.629 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.110.335,63 R$ 0,00 R$ 22.110.335,63 

PRECISA SISTEMAS DE INFORMATICA LTDA 94.468.030 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.841.793,23 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.841.793,23 

DALMEDSUL MEDIC EIRELI 04.497.941 R$ 1.369.833,47 R$ 20.471.590,97 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.841.424,44 

HOSPL GAUCHA LTDA 93.140.564 R$ 6.433,73 R$ 21.727.772,13 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.734.205,86 

UNIAO DAS COOPERATIVAS DO SUL LTDA UNICOOP 91.604.041 R$ 7.125.275,15 R$ 14.589.807,90 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.715.083,05 

KOBA IND E COM DE PLASTICOS EIRELI 74.140.450 R$ 1.527.188,04 R$ 19.823.453,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.350.641,04 

USACON IND DE CONFEC LTDA 89.295.208 R$ 5.395.056,13 R$ 15.822.572,55 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.217.628,68 

SAWE COSMETICOS EIRELI 07.668.618 R$ 8.516.685,06 R$ 12.660.728,04 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.177.413,10 

IND E COM TOJOQUIM LTDA 01.506.081 R$ 1.467.555,78 R$ 19.704.821,96 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.172.377,74 

B & V DIST DE MED E COR MAT MED HOSP E OF LTDA 01.641.492 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.147.009,93 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.147.009,93 

JOAO ESCOSTEGUY S/A TEC E CONFECCOES 92.689.579 R$ 15.980.183,21 R$ 5.056.212,71 R$ 0,00 R$ 21.036.395,92 

BESSEY METALURGIA S A 88.155.700 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.995.277,71 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.995.277,71 

INCOARROZ S/A BENEFIC E COM DE ARROZ 92.197.300 R$ 11.910.520,27 R$ 9.026.524,22 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.937.044,49 

TRANSPORTADORA J L LTDA 91.425.272 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.931.845,05 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.931.845,05 

CIONELI IND DE CALCADOS LTDA 87.557.336 R$ 20.917.010,06 R$ 0,00 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.917.010,06 

COML CERRO BRANCO LTDA 07.608.180 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.824.259,38 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.824.259,38 

BONSUL IND E COM DE CARNES E DERIVADOS LTDA 01.738.060 R$ 175.488,15 R$ 20.625.561,07 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.801.049,22 

GAZOLA S/A IND METALURGICA 88.611.983 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.767.174,66 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.767.174,66 

TRANSPA TRANSTERMA LTDA 07.086.422 R$ 485.012,83 R$ 20.272.024,84 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.757.037,67 

C A MEDEIROS & FREITAS LTDA 73.936.510 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.710.967,02 R$ 0,00 R$ 20.710.967,02
```