# Iteration through a list using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to iterate a limited number of `<span>` elements from html, which are actually lists generated from webdriver.

I've tried doing this:

```
for i in range(9):
    print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "thead > tr th:nth-child("+[i]+") > span").text)
```

And I received the following error:

> print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody > tr
> td:nth-child("+[i]+") > span").text) TypeError: can only concatenate
> str (not "list") to str

Here is the html snippet:

```html
<thead><tr class="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(xs) Ta(end)"><th class="Ta(start) W(100px) Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Date</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Open</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>High</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Low</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Close*</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Adj Close**</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Volume</span></th></tr></thead>
```

It's all from this page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-EUR/history

Comment: seems like that should be just "i" not "[i]".  You can probably just use find_elements and let the locator do the work for you.  Then iterate over the webelement array that find_elements returns.

Comment: But with find_elements I cant put a limited number of iterations and I need it.

Comment: You find the elements and iterate them. Try `driver.find_elements` this will return a list of we element and iterate through it

Comment: Even better would just use position()<10(index starts at 1) as an xpath to find all the td .

Comment: @ArundeepChohan what do you mean? Is that position a function from selenium or the css property?

Comment: @MahmodulHaque I need to find only ten span elements, sorry, i forgot to mention that. `.find_elements` gets everything, Didnt see how to limit it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the [*Update* section of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025446/7429447) to extract the text only from the first `<span>` which is a decendent of the first `<th>` and you are restricting the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447) as:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "thead > tr th:nth-child(1) > span")
```

---

### This usecase

To iterate through all the `<span>` elements from html of the [website](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-EUR/history) you can use [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-EUR/history')
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "thead > tr th > span")))])
```

Console Output:

```
['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close*', 'Adj Close**', 'Volume', 'Symbol', 'Last Price', 'Change', '% Change']
```

To retrict the number of elements within the [*List*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70826950/7429447) to ***9*** elements you can use:

```
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-EUR/history')
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "thead > tr th > span")))][:9])
```