# Get the src value from a list of webelements with Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

Hello trying to adapt a solution from this video

```
#scroller 100 fois pour reveler le plus d'image ( comment etre sur qu'on est à la fin ?)
n_scrolls = 100
for i in range(1, n_scrolls):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)
    #recupère toutes les balises img puis leurs attribut src (je ne comprend pa bien cette façon d'assigner les elements)
    images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
    print(images)
    images = [images.get_attribute('src') for img in images]
```

But the output is:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="50f35cc8388f3b59df4042bcc09c7079", element="4a4b2838-67d6-4787-a168-9e25e948a21a")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="50f35cc8388f3b59df4042bcc09c7079", element="7e3ae8f5-160a-4da6-b3a7-2be10bad8f3f")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="50f35cc8388f3b59df4042bcc09c7079", element="8c45c421-3f25-4498-85a2-565506835984")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="50f35cc8388f3b59df4042bcc09c7079", element="5ef69be7-13d7-41f1-9ec8-d8ac6e843fdd")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="50f35cc8388f3b59df4042bcc09c7079", element="626ae474-bccc-40c3-ac60-5b5f021b7bf0")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="50f35cc8388f3b59df4042bcc09c7079", element="ea0b589d-8e90-470a-ad59-a661f8d52b31")>
```

Instead of the img tag element, is it possible to get the src attributes?

Comment: Move your print one line down.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan i get the error " 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' " that why i have moved it up to see what is inside the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find the mistake you have made.

Instead of this

```
images = [images.get_attribute('src') for img in images]
```

It should be

```
images = [img.get_attribute('src') for img in images]
```

Since you are iterating the list.

Now print the list you will get all `src` values.

`print(images)`

Answer (score 1):

As *`images`* is the list of the `<img>` elements, while iterating the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) within the `for` loop you need to extract the *`src`* attribute from each individual ***img*** and also may like to avoid editing the same [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) and create a different [*list*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70826950/7429447) altogether. So effectively, your line of code will be:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
print(images)
image_src_list = [img.get_attribute('src') for img in images]
print(image_src_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! all work fine now ! are you dedicate to solve the selenium troubleshoot on stackoverflow ? that not the first time that i see your profile on , if yes have you a script to be alerted by each related question ?

Comment: Contributions  on [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) tag is purely a community effort. You can always join us. Feel free to join us in the [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.