# Selenium - How to get values with the same tag name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am stuck at one end, I am not able to get values.

For better view... I need to get these values

1)809

```
<td class="tdResult" id="tdResultSpFlights" onclick="consultaSpFlights(809,1);" style="cursor:pointer;"><u>809</u></td>
```

2)2

```
<td class="tdResult" id="tdResultSpCanceledFlights" onclick="consultaSpCanceledFlights(2,1);" style="cursor:pointer;"><u>2</u></td>
```

3)90

```
<td class="tdResult" id="tdResultSpDelayedFlights" onclick="consultaSpDelayedFlights(90,1);" style="cursor:pointer;"><u>90</u></td>
```

If I use

```
find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"u")
```

Applying with the first one is correct, but i cannot get the others, due to they has the same tag name. I already try with xpath, class and id. How can i get values above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element()` will return the first matching element. Instead you need to use **`find_elements()`** and to extract the texts you can use a [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) as follows:

```
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "u")])
```