# Looping through elements with Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, loops, list-comprehension, webdriverwait

Im having trouble working through the following problem.
Im trying to collect the data from the following webpage:https://localhelp.healthcare.gov/#/results?q=UTAH&lat=0&lng=0&city=&state=UT&zip_code=&mp=FFM

My method is to use the Selenium chrome driver to collect the data, for each healthcare agent, off this webpage, but dont know how I would loop through each record and add the data to each created list. So far, I can collect the data for a single record, but my problem is with my loop. How would I identify each record as an agent, and add that to my data frame for output? here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  # connect python with webbrowser-chrome
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/picka/Documents/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://localhelp.healthcare.gov/#/results?q=UTAH&lat=0&lng=0&city=&state=UT&zip_code=&mp=FFM'

name = []
phone = []
email = []

def go_to_network():
    driver.get(url)

    for agent in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('class.qa-flh-results-list'):
        
        get_name = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.qa-flh-resource-name"))).text)
        get_phone = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.qa-flh-resource-phone"))).text)
        get_email = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.ds-u-overflow--hidden.ds-u-truncate.ds-u-display--inline-block"))).text)

        name.append(get_name)
        phone.append(get_phone)
        email.append(get_email)


go_to_network()


record_output = {'Agent Name': name, 'Phone': phone, 'Email':  email}
df = pd.DataFrame(record_output)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\picka\Documents\Dev\Reports\Agent-data.csv', header=True, index=False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract and print all the *Agent Name*, *Phone* and *Email* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) you can use [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://localhelp.healthcare.gov/#/results?q=UTAH&lat=0&lng=0&city=&state=UT&zip_code=&mp=FFM')
  get_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.qa-flh-resource-name")))]
  get_phone = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.qa-flh-resource-phone")))]
  get_email = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.ds-u-overflow--hidden.ds-u-truncate.ds-u-display--inline-block")))]
  for i,j,k in zip(get_name, get_phone, get_email):
    print(f"{i}'s' phone number is {j} and email is {k}")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Wesley Elton's' phone number is (801) 404 - 2424 and email is wes@wallbrokers.com
  Raquel Bell's' phone number is (801) 842 - 2870 and email is raquel.bell@enroll365.org
  Brandon Berglund's' phone number is (801) 981 - 9414 and email is Brandon@BerglundIns.com
  Steven Cochran's' phone number is (801) 800 - 8360 and email is steve.cochran@gbsbenefits.com
  victoria dang's' phone number is (801) 462 - 5190 and email is victoriawfg@yahoo.com
  Dan Jessop's' phone number is (435) 232 - 8833 and email is dejessop@hotmail.com
  Billy Gerdts's' phone number is (801) 280 - 1162 and email is bgerdts@gginsurancegroup.com
  Michael Saldana's' phone number is (801) 879 - 1032 and email is saldana.michael25@gmail.com
  Brandon Johnson's' phone number is (435) 249 - 0725 and email is brandon@msiagency.com
  Matthew Selph's' phone number is (801) 918 - 3945 and email is selph7@gmail.com
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Awesome, that at least gets each record appropriatly. but how would I add each agent record as their own row inside of my dataframe for csv output?

Comment: Sounds like a different question all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?