# Selenium cant puul the products prices from a website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a program that reads data from a [website](https://www.myperfume.co.il/155567-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8?order=up_title) using selenium. In this case I want to get the prices of the perfumes.

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("spam.items_show_price_text"):
    print(i.text)
```

When I run the program it prints for me 139 empty lines(139 is the number of the perfumes that are in the website).
I guess it has to do with the `"span.items_show_price_text"` parameter of the driver.find_elements_by_css_selector function.

The whole code (there is no need to understand the while loop, it is basicly runs the program for all of the page, because it is loding when you scroll down)

```
from datetime import date

import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

urlM = 'https://www.myperfume.co.il/155567-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91' \
       '%D7%A8?order=up_title&page=0'
urlF = 'https://www.myperfume.co.il/155569-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99' \
       '%D7%A9%D7%94?order=up_title&page=0'

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("credentials.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

spreadsheet = client.open("Perfumes")

options = ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

namesM = []
pricesM = []
namesMe = ' '

lenM = 0

num = 0
while len(namesMe) != 0:
    urlM = urlM[:-1] + str(int(urlM[-1]) + 1)

    # ---=MALE=---
    driver.get(urlM)
    # names
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3.title.text-center"):
        lenM += 1
        namesM.append(i.text)
    # prices
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("spam.items_show_price_text"):
    print(i.text)
        print(i.text)
```

Comment: Please share all your code

Comment: I shared but its not that relevant

Comment: @Prophet I just nned the right parameter for the find_elements_by_css_selector function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see on that site, the locator for actual prices (after the price off) will be

```py
'span.price'
```

So, instead of

```py
for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("spam.items_show_price_text"):
```

Try using

```py
for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.price"):
```

You should also add waits/ delays there.
Again, it is preferably to use Expected Conditions explicit waits for that.
And don't mess `spam` with `span` :)

Comment: Thanks a LOT! that worked pretty well.
Can you please share where you found the locator?

Comment: you are sincerely welcome יהב :)

Comment: How did you find the right locator? it will help a lot!

Comment: This is a `span` with class names `price center-price-in-grid text-right` So you can simply use `span.price.center-price-in-grid.text-right` locator but a quick check shows that `price` class name is unique so `span.price` is unique enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190345/can-selenium-click-on-diffrents-links
If you have some time to help, Ill be very glad