# Can selenium click on diffrents links?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to scrap data from this [website](https://www.myperfume.co.il/155567-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8?order=up_title&page=1)(Ignore the perfume that it loads when you scroll down).

For each perfume i want to get its size. In order to see its size I need to click on the perfume which leading me to another page.
Assuming I can get the size of a perfume when Im in its url, How can I make a program that will give me the url of every perfume's page in the website?

This is the code that finds the perfume`s size when I Have the right url:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

urlM = 'https://www.myperfume.co.il/155567-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91' \
       '%D7%A8?order=up_title&page=0'
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("credentials.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

spreadsheet = client.open("Perfumes")

options = ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get(# [THE PERFUME'S URL]... )
info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[(@id = "item_current_sub_title")]//span').text
res = ''
for i in info[:info.find('\n')].replace('גודל', ''):
    if i.isdigit() or i.isalpha():
        res += i
print(res)
```

Comment: Yes you can. I would suggest getting the xpath to the first item and then the second and seeing how they are similar. Based on that make a loop and get all of them on the page. Another option is to capture the larger object, being the entire list and go through each of its children (each entry) and get the link of each child.

Comment: but the size of the perfume isnt available when youre on the main page, you can only access it when you click each perfume

Comment: Yes I understand that. So you will need to go through one by one and click on them. I would try opening them in a new tab. Switching to that tab (single item) and then getting the current url(save to a variable). Switch back to the original tab (listing page) and then close the single item window. You will have the url in your current url variable.

Comment: Do you have a short code to get a list of all of the the perfumes url?
I know you cna do this by checking the url element in each perfume but i dont know how to access this element..

Comment: This will get you a list. You will need to go through each of the items and check if their children have an a tag. "browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="element_161268"]').find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you will need the following:
Per each product hover over the product to make "more details" and "add to cart" buttons appear.
Click the "more details" button.
In the opened page get the product size (and any other details).
Get back to the main page.
In order to do that for many products you will have to get the list of products again on the main page. Otherwise you will get stale element exception.
So, your code can be something like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")))
time.sleep(1)
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")
for i in range(len(products)):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")))
    time.sleep(1)
    product = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")[i]
    #hover over the product block
    actions.move_to_element(product).perform()
    #click the "mode details button
    product.find_element_by_xpath(".//p[contains(@class,'extra_button')]").click()
    #in the details page get the product sub-title containing the product size
    product_size = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#item_current_sub_title"))).text
    #get back to the main page
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

**UPD**
This is exactly what I run:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

urlM = 'https://www.myperfume.co.il/155567-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91' \
       '%D7%A8?order=up_title&page=0'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)


driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(urlM)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")))
time.sleep(1)
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")
for i in range(len(products)):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")))
    time.sleep(1)
    product = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item')]")[i]
    #hover over the product block
    actions.move_to_element(product).perform()
    #click the "mode details button
    product.find_element_by_xpath(".//p[contains(@class,'extra_button')]").click()
    #in the details page get the product sub-title containing the product size
    product_size = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#item_current_sub_title"))).text
    product_size = product_size.split('\n')[0]
    print(product_size)
    #get back to the main page
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

And it prints me the products sizes like `גודל: 100 ML`

Comment: what is `pager` in your 12 line?

Comment: Copy-paste issue, I'm sorry. Fixed that

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, it isnt working for me. it gives me this warning for your 10th line:
Class 'WebElement' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances.
Posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193551/cant-get-the-products-size-form-a-website

Comment: I see your new question. Do you mean this line `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'layout_list_item.item')]")[i]`? I use `find_elements_by_xpath` method, it returns a list of web elements.

Comment: @YahavB: I have closed this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193551/cant-get-the-products-size-form-a-website?noredirect=1, cause you already have an answer here.

Comment: This answer didnt work for me, So i tried to improve it and build a new code, I am asking for the new code, please bring back the question

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work for you? I see you've accepted the answer. @Prophet I believe your code is working?

Comment: @cruisepandey it should, I didn't actually try that. Currently I'm trying to reproduce that on my PC.

Comment: @YahavB I have tested that and fixed the issue. The main problem was with a locator.  I have checked, now it works

Comment: @Prophet can you please put all of your code?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the answer with my actual code.

Comment: Partly, but it is not relevant anymore. Thank you!!