# How to find every element on page using attributes without values?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

*Example code*

```
<a href="/cristiano/" title="cristiano">\<span class="\_7UhW9   xLCgt        qyrsm KV-D4           se6yk       T0kll "\>cristiano\</span\></a>
```

How to tell python to find every element with *class*, *title*, *href*, and *tabindex* attributes. Then get the "title" value for each.

tried `find_element_by_xpath` but no result

Comment: Any particular library you want to use? Something able interpret XPath-syntax may be a valid choice.

Comment: @Prophet Possibly you have massacred the question in an attempt to format it. Currently text are depicted as code and code is depicted as text.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I just added the `xpath` tag there. But I'll take a look to format the question now

Comment: @Prophet Thanks for addressing the breakage. Now looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `"//*[@attribute_name]"` i.e.
to get all the elements with `title` attribute the XPath is `"//*[@title]"`,
to get all the elements with `class` attribute the XPath is `"//*[@class]"`,
to get all the elements with `href` attribute the XPath is `"//*[@href]"`
etc.
So, to get all the `title` attribute values from all the elements on the page you can do something like this:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@title]")
for element in elements:
    title = element.get_attribute("title")
    print(title)
```

etc.
In case you want to locate all elements having `title` **and** `class` **and** `href` attributes, all the 3 in each all of them, it will look like this:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@title and @class and @href]")
for element in elements:
    title_val = element.get_attribute("title")
    class_val = element.get_attribute("class")
    href_val = element.get_attribute("href")
    print(title_val)
    print(class_val)
    print(href_val)
```

Comment: So if I want to have them all "//*[@title] and *[@class] and *[@href]"
 is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean: you want to locate all elements having both `title` **and** `class` **and** `href` attributes?

Comment: I mean elements having all the 3 attributes in them?

Comment: exactly that's what I want

Comment: Please see my updated naswer

Comment: Yes. It worked but one more question. What if I want to have only *span* or *a* elements. Will it look like *//a*[[at]title and [at]class and [at]href and [at]tabindex]* or *//a//*[[at]title and [at]class and [at]href and [at]tabindex]*? Thanks! (These [at]s are basically @)

Comment: `//a[@title and @class and @href]` and `'//span[@title and @class and @href]'` accordingly

Comment: or you want the element to be `a` **or** `span` only

Answer (score 0):

To find every element with *class*, *title*, *href* and textract the value of the *`title`* attribute for each of the items you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("title") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href and @title][.//span[@class and text()]]")])
  ```
- Inducing  [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447):

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("title") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href and @title][.//span[@class and text()]]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```