# How to get text from a html using Selenium and Python which has two elements with the same classname where I need to extract both

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a html like:

```
<div class='mesage-in'> cool text here </div>
<div class='mesage-in'> bad text here </div>
```

and my python code like:

```
texto = navegador.find_element_by_class_name('message-in').text
print(texto)
```

Is it possible make this get all elements with same class name and put on a array or define as different variable like this?

OutPut:

```
print(texto1)

-> cool text here

print(texto2)

-> bad text here
```

#or

```
print(texto[0])

-> cool text here

print(texto[1])

-> bad text here
```

Actualy my code only get the first one

Comment: my exemple has only 2 elements with same class name, but in the html has a lot

Comment: Try `.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='message-in']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML:

```
<div class='mesage-in'> cool text here </div>
<div class='mesage-in'> bad text here </div>
```

The following line line of code:

```
texto = navegador.find_element_by_class_name('message-in').text
```

will always identify the first matching element, extract the text and assign it to *`texto`*. So when you try to print *`texto`*, the text of the very first element i.e. ***cool text here*** is printed.

---

### Solution

You can get all elements with same classname i.e. *`mesage-in`* and put on a list as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
texto = navegador.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'message-in')
```

Now you can print the desired texts with respect to their index as follows:

- To print *cool text here*:

  ```
  print(texto[0].text) # prints-> cool text here
  ```
- To print *bad text here*:

  ```
  print(texto[1].text) # prints-> bad text here
  ```

---

### Outro

You can also crate a list of the texts using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) and print them as follows:

```
texto = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "message-in")]
print(texto[0]) # prints-> cool text here
print(texto[1]) # prints-> bad text here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using BeautifulSoup library.

example output :

> [' cool text here ', ' bad text here ']

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_class_texts(html_text: str, class_name: str):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, features="html.parser")
    return [tag.text for tag in soup.select(f".{class_name}")]

print(get_class_texts("<div class='mesage-in'> cool text here </div> <div class ='mesage-in'> bad text here </div>", "mesage-in"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple elements into one array you need to use find_elements. In your case I would use xpath like so:

```
eleArray = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class='mesage-in']');
```

Then, you can loop over the array like so:

```
for element in eleArray:
    print(element.text)
```

Here is a similar example where I get all latin encodeable span elements from wikipedia and log them to a console. Feel free to run it and see the results (this product is free to use by the way, so you can transfer the test case and make your own account via google login):
https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/a320a3ad-9949-4bce-87fa-7a0980df8f1f?projectId=bugtestproject2

Answer (score 0):

You can store them into a list. That list will be a list of web elements.

As I see, you are using `navegador.find_element` which will return a single web element.

Whereas `navegador.find_elements` will return a list of web elements.

Also, in latest Selenium `find_element_by_class_name` have been deprecated therefore I would suggest you to use `navegador.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "")`

**Code:**

```
texto = navegador.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'message-in')
print(texto[0])
print(texto[1])

or 

for txt in texto:
    print(txt.text)
```