# How to extract the text from the webelements using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, text, webdriverwait

Code trials:

```
driver.get(url)
cards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("job-cardstyle__JobCardComponent-sc-1mbmxes-0")
for card in cards:
    data = card.get_attribute('text')
    print(data)

    
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The "cards" is returning selenium webelement and I am not able to extract the text from it by for loop.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: try `data = card.text`

Comment: returning None.

Comment: card. text is not working. returning empty spaces

Comment: Then that means there is no text (or the text is `''`) to return. Please share the url if you'd like further help.

Comment: Try to get the details from this page . https://www.monster.com/jobs/search?q=Python-Developer&where=Las+Vegas%2C+NV&page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works to an extent:

```
driver.get("https://www.monster.com/jobs/search?q=Python-Developer&where=Las+Vegas%2C+NV&page=1")
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-test-id = 'svx-job-title']")))
jobs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'job-cardstyle__JobCardHeader')]")
all_jobs = [job.text for job in jobs]
print(all_jobs)
```

WebdriverWait imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Output:

```
['Software engineer III\nRandstad USA\nLas Vegas, NV', 'C\nPython Developer\nconfidential\n$55 - $65 / Per Hour', 'C\nSenior Software Engineer\nCox Communications Inc\nLas Vegas, NV', 'Mission Systems Engineer\nDCS Corporation\nLas Vegas, NV', 'G\nSoftware Engineer - 914\nGCR Technical Staffing\nHenderson, NV', 'Z\nNetSuite Developer\nZone & Company Software Consulting\nLas Vegas, NV', 'IT Project Engineer\nRauland Florida by Ametek, Inc.\nSunrise, NV', 'A\nWeb Developer\nArdor Global', 'Senior Software Engineer – Node\nMeridian Technology Group Inc.']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You may split the list with `\n` delimiter for further usage. Also, seems like this site loads the cards dynamically, i.e., as you scroll down, new cards load up, so you may not get all the cards in one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `get_attribute('text')` you need to use the [*`text`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute as follows:

```
data = card.text
```

---

### Solution

To locate the ***visible*** elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get(url)
cards = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "job-cardstyle__JobCardComponent-sc-1mbmxes-0")))
for card in cards:
    data = card.text
    print(data)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Outro

In a single line you can use [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) as follows:

```
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "job-cardstyle__JobCardComponent-sc-1mbmxes-0")))])
```

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your webelement path whether correctly mentioned or not
2. get the text from element
3. Print it

Answer (score 0):

Issue is at this line

```
 data = card.get_attribute('text')
```

You can do the following:

1. Use `.text`

   ```
   for card in cards:
    data = card.text
    print(data)
   ```
2. Use `innerText`

   ```
   for card in cards:
    data = card.get_attribute('innerText')
    print(data)
   ```

Also, as per the comment above, you should print cards list length to debug it better.

```
print(len(cards))
```

so if it has something in it or not.