# Unable to retrieve the href attributes using Python and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, list-comprehension, href

I'm very new to this and have spent hours trying various methods I've read here. Apologies if I'm making some silly mistake

I want to create a database of my LEGO sets. Pulling images and info from brickset.com

I'm using:

```
anchors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-tabs-2"]/ul/li[1]/a')
anchors = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in anchors]
```

print (anchors) returns:

```
anchors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-tabs-2"]/ul/li[1]/a')
```

What I'm trying to target:

```
div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
<ul class="moreimages">
<li>
<a href="https://images.brickset.com/sets/AdditionalImages/21054-1/21054_alt10.jpg" class="highslide plain " onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="https://images.brickset.com/sets/AdditionalImages/21054-1/tn_21054_alt10_jpg.jpg" title="" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/spacer2.png'" loading="lazy">
</a><div class="highslide-caption">
```

I'm losing my mind trying to figure this out.

**Update**
Still not getting the href attributes. To add more detail, I'm trying to get the images under the "images" tab on this URL:
https://brickset.com/sets/21330-1/Home-Alone
Here is the problematic code:

```
anchors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ui-tabs-2"]/ul/li/a')
links = [anchors.get_attribute('href') for a in anchors]
print('Found ' + str(len(anchors)) + ' links to images')
```

I've also tried:

```
#anchors = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='21330']")
```

This only returned one href, even though there should be about a dozen.

Thank you all for the assistance!

Comment: Can you share a sample URL and a desired output?

Comment: Here is one example: https://brickset.com/sets/21330-1/Home-Alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the same name for multiple variables.

As per the first line of code:

```
anchors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-tabs-2"]/ul/li[1]/a')
```

`anchors` is the list of WebElements. Ideally to create another list with the *`href`* attributes you should use another name, e.g. ***hrefs***

Effectively your code block will be:

```
anchors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-tabs-2"]/ul/li[1]/a')
hrefs = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in anchors]
print(hrefs)
```

Using [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) in a single line:

```
print(a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-tabs-2"]/ul/li[1]/a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` is deprecated, use `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'locator')` instead.

Now, if you'd like to get all `href`s of the links on the page:

```py
elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ui-tabs-2"]/ul/li/a')
links = [element.get_attribute('href') for element in elements]
```

Notice that I'm not using `[1]` to get a single element, but rather all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this.

**NOTE:** I'm not using `selenium` here.

```py
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0",
}

sample_urls = [
    "https://brickset.com/sets/21330-1/Home-Alone",
    "https://brickset.com/sets/21101-1/Hayabusa"
]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for sample_url in sample_urls:
        ajax_setID = [
            a["href"] for a in
            BeautifulSoup(s.get(sample_url, headers=headers).text, "lxml").find_all("a")
            if "mainImage" in a["href"]
        ][0]
        image_url = f"https://brickset.com{ajax_setID}&_{int(time.time() * 1000)}"
        headers.update(
            {
                "Referer": sample_url,
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            }
        )
        source_image = (
            BeautifulSoup(
                s.get(image_url, headers=headers).text, "lxml"
            ).find("img")["src"]
        )
        print(f"{sample_url.split('/', -1)[-1]} -> {source_image}")
```

This should output:

```
Home-Alone -> https://images.brickset.com/sets/images/21330-1.jpg?202109060933
Hayabusa -> https://images.brickset.com/sets/images/21101-1.jpg?201201150457
```