# How to print the hidden product names using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Second ever post here. Still new to all this. Having trouble with a simple print call in a for loop not displaying any text, yet moving the cursor as if it did. If I check the length, it matches with how many spaces are moved in the print call (12)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser= webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers-intl-ship&field-keywords=&ref=nb_sb_noss&crid=JKZZMSQ4Q71E&sprefix=%2Ccomputers-intl-ship%2C114')
elem_list= browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.a-section.a-spacing-medium._octopus-search-result-card_style_apbSearchResultsContainer__bCqjb")
items = elem_list.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@data-component-type="s-product-image"]')
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

if I run

```
print(len(items))
```

I get 12. However once I run the above mentioned for loop, I simply get 12 blank empty spaces. What am I doing wrong?

---

### Update

I'm thinking the problem is in the data component type being an image. But after inspecting all the elements, what's best practice for displaying the list of items on the page that I am trying to do?

Comment: You are basically looking for `//span[@data-component-type="s-product-image"]`, As I see on the webpage, it does not have any text so doing `.text` is returning a space or empty line. What text do you want to extract?

Comment: My desired outcome is having it print the text below each picture. Basically listing all the text of the products on the page in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***product names*** are contained within the ***`alt`*** attribute of the *`<img>`* elements.

---

### Solution

To extract the product names using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following *locator strategies*:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers-intl-ship&field-keywords=&ref=nb_sb_noss&crid=JKZZMSQ4Q71E&sprefix=%2Ccomputers-intl-ship%2C114")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("alt") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-component-type='s-product-image']>a>div>img")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers-intl-ship&field-keywords=&ref=nb_sb_noss&crid=JKZZMSQ4Q71E&sprefix=%2Ccomputers-intl-ship%2C114")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("alt") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-component-type='s-product-image']/a/div/img")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Apple Pencil (2nd Generation)', 'Sceptre 24" Professional Thin 75Hz 1080p LED Monitor 2x HDMI VGA Build-in Speakers, Machine Black (E248W-19203R Series)', 'Roku Streaming Stick 4K 2021 | Streaming Device 4K/HDR/Dolby Vision with Roku Voice Remote and TV Controls', 'Original HP 67XL Black High-yield Ink Cartridge | Works with HP DeskJet 1255, 2700, 4100 Series, HP ENVY 6000, 6400 Series...', 'Seagate Portable 2TB External Hard Drive Portable HDD – USB 3.0 for PC, Mac, PlayStation, & Xbox - 1-Year Rescue Service (...', 'Logitech MK270 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo for Windows, 2.4 GHz Wireless, Compact Mouse, 8 Multimedia and Shortcut K...', 'Original HP 67 Black/Tri-color Ink Cartridges (2-pack) | Works with HP DeskJet 1255, 2700, 4100 Series, HP ENVY 6000, 6400...', 'HP 24mh FHD Monitor - Computer Monitor with 23.8-Inch IPS Display (1080p) - Built-In Speakers and VESA Mounting - Height/T...', 'iPhone Charger, TAKAGI Lightning Cable 3PACK 6FT Nylon Braided USB Charging Cable High Speed Data Sync Transfer Cord Compa...', 'Original HP 63XL Black High-yield Ink Cartridge | Works with HP DeskJet 1112, 2130, 3630 Series; HP ENVY 4510, 4520 Serie...', 'Roku Express 4K+ 2021 | Streaming Media Player HD/4K/HDR with Smooth Wireless Streaming and Roku Voice Remote with TV Cont...', 'Logitech C920x HD Pro Webcam, Full HD 1080p/30fps Video Calling, Clear Stereo Audio, HD Light Correction, Works with Skyp...']
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the info, its very helpful. Since driver isn't defined, do I have to import that as well since it is not defined in this scenario? Thank you!

Comment: Just replace `driver` with `browser` as per your code.

Comment: Ugh lol, yup, my bad.