# How to find the value of all the id attribute of all the button elements in a web page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, tagname

Suppose there are multiple buttons in a web page

```
<button id='xyz'></button>
<button id='abc'></button>
<button id='pqr'></button>
```

I want the value of the id attributes of all the buttons using selenium

I am using this code

```
for button in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value='//button'):
   print(button.get_attribute('id'))
```

I am not getting any thing in the output

Answer (score 0):

Considering the HTML

```
<button id='xyz'></button>
<button id='abc'></button>
<button id='pqr'></button>
```

To extract the value of the *`id`* attributes of the *`<button>`* elements you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *TAG_NAME*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("id") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "button")))])
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("id") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("id") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```