# How to extract multiple texts from span elements using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, list-comprehension

I am trying to extract all the texts in span into list, using the following HTML code from Selenium webdriver method:

```
['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', ' ', ' ', '3a', '3b', '3c', '4a', ' ', ' ']
```

Anyone expert know how to do it?

HTML:

```
<tr style="background-color:#999">
    <td><b style="white-space: nowrap;">table_num</b><enter code here/td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span style="flex: 1;display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
                <span>1a</span>
                <span>1b</span>
                <span>1c</span>
                </span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span style="flex: 1;display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
                <span>2a</span>
                <span>　　　　　</span>
                <span>　　　　　</span>
           </span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span style="flex: 1;display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
                <span>3a</span>
                <span>3b</span>
                <span>3c</span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span style="flex: 1;display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
                <span>4a</span>
                <span>　　　　　</span>
                <span>　　　　　</span>
            </span>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have written till now, we will try to resolve the problem which you are facing.

Comment: Below is the code I have written. So far only managed to get result for 1a, 1b and 1c. Any expert to help?

print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(.,'table_num')]/following-sibling::td[1]"))).text)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way, use the below `xpath` which will give you all the required `spans`.

```
//span[contains(@style,"column")]/span
```

Once you have all the span, you have to extract text from it.

If there is empty text, then ignore or else add it in the list.

Comment: Thanks! But do you know how I can code it so it extract all span texts (including empty text) from using 'table_num' instead?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML, to extract all the texts from the *`<span>`* elements into a *list* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("application url")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[style^='background'] > td td > span span")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`get_attribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  driver.get("application url")     
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[starts-with(@style, 'background')]/td//td/span//span")))])
  ```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I extract all span texts (including empty) from using the 'table_num' text instead?

Comment: What does the code in the answer prints using css and xpath?

Comment: Hi, I actually realized I using "html_page = driver.page_source" to get the html code:

I edit your code abit but still see errors:

css:
----
html_page = driver.page_source
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(html_page, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[style^='background'] > td td > span span")))])

ERROR:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_elements'

Comment: xpath:
------
html_page = driver.page_source

print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(html_page, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[starts-with(@style, 'background')]/td//td/span//span")))])


ERROR:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_elements'

Comment: Do you know the problem?

Comment: You don't have to `html_page = driver.page_source`, simply access the page. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Now I run the CSS code and got this error. You know the problem?

ERROR-1:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Al PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Al PC\PycharmProjects\Fi\fi.py", line 524, in py_and_pt_click

Comment: ERROR-1-1:
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[style^='background'] > td td > span span")))])
  File "C:\Users\Al PC\PycharmProjects\SocialMedia\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I try 60 delay also same error. You know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the predicate `[1]` from XPath, so it becomes:

```
//td[contains(.,'table_num')]/following-sibling::td
```

En to be more precise you could use:

```
//td[contains(.,'table_num')]/following-sibling::td/span/span
```