# How to loop over elements with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to use selenium to loop over a few divs on a webpage and find the content of the divs

The basic setup of the webpage looks like this:

```
<html>
   <div data-testid="property-card">
       <div data-testid="title">content 1</div>
   </div>
   <div data-testid="property-card">
       <div data-testid="title">content 2</div>
   </div>
   <div data-testid="property-card">
       <div data-testid="title">content 3</div>
   </div>
</html>
```

and here is my code:

```
def report_results(self):
    hotel_boxes = self.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="property-card"]')
    for hotel in hotel_boxes:
        hotel_name = hotel.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="title"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        print(hotel_name)
```

However, the problem is that this only prints "content 1" for three times. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, the only 1 thing you are missing is a dot `.` at the front of XPath expression.
It should be

```py
hotel_name = hotel.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="title"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

When using `'//div[@data-testid="title"]'` XPath expression it will search for the matching locator **from the top of the page** until it finds the **first match**.
While when we have that dot `.` it means to start searching **inside** the current node i.e. inside the parent element `hotel`
So, your entire code can be:

```py
def report_results(self):
    hotel_boxes = self.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="property-card"]')
    for hotel in hotel_boxes:
        hotel_name = hotel.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="title"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        print(hotel_name)
```

Answer (score -2):

As per the given HTML:

```
<html>
   <div data-testid="property-card">
       <div data-testid="title">content 1</div>
   </div>
   <div data-testid="property-card">
       <div data-testid="title">content 2</div>
   </div>
   <div data-testid="property-card">
       <div data-testid="title">content 3</div>
   </div>
</html>
```

To print the *`innerText`* of the descendant `<div>` tags you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72573441/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='property-card'] > [data-testid='title']")])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`.get_attribute('innerHTML')`*:

  ```
  print([my_elem..get_attribute('innerHTML') for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='property-card']/div[@data-testid='title']")])
  ```