# find_elementS with get_atributes("innerHTML")

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following situation

```
values = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "roulette-history-item__value-textsiwxWvFlm3ohr_UMS23f")
```

I get list with 260 keys, So far, okay!
However, I need this simplified list, with just the text

```
values = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "roulette-history-item__value-textsiwxWvFlm3ohr_UMS23f").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Is there any possibility to get something like this above? With **find_element** it works fine.
find_element**S** not work.

A loop with values[x].text is too slow.
I tested it with a simple array, without the ".text" and it's 1000x faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
values = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "roulette-history-item__value-textsiwxWvFlm3ohr_UMS23f")
for value in values:
    v = value.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: That works, if you want all the values in a list format you could also: `value_list = [value.get_attribute("innerHTML") for value in values]`

Comment: Just append() method is enough in that case

Answer (score 0):

To extract the ***innerHTML*** or the texts from all the matching elements you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *`get_attribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "roulette-history-item__value-textsiwxWvFlm3ohr_UMS23f")])
  ```
- Using *text*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "roulette-history-item__value-textsiwxWvFlm3ohr_UMS23f")])
  ```