# Selenium Python extracting information from a website and dumping it into JSON Format

Tags: python, json, selenium, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm trying to open a Hotel website [www.booking.com](http://www.booking.com) and extract the name, price, location, and link from the top 50 search results which are sorted by cheapest first. I'm using Selenium python to automate the process However some HTML elements are targetable while others are not.
after inspecting the website I realized that all hotel names have the class name: `fcab3ed991 a23c043802`

I tried to target all of them and put them into an array as seen in my code below. But I can't seem to target the element correctly. What I'm I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAKIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AvqR75YGwAIB0gIkZDQ4MTdjZDctYzIyNC00N2RlLWJhYjItZDU1YTAwMGU2M2Q12AIF4AIB&sid=8005d0cc6b75af8d0d2e74451b73cb8b&aid=304142&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAKIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AvqR75YGwAIB0gIkZDQ4MTdjZDctYzIyNC00N2RlLWJhYjItZDU1YTAwMGU2M2Q12AIF4AIB%26sid%3D8005d0cc6b75af8d0d2e74451b73cb8b%26sb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%26&ss=Jumeirah%2C+Dubai%2C+Dubai+Emirate%2C+United+Arab+Emirates&is_ski_area=&checkin_year=2022&checkin_month=8&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2022&checkout_month=8&checkout_monthday=3&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&map=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&ss_raw=jum&ac_position=1&ac_langcode=en&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=941&dest_type=district&place_id_lat=25.205553&place_id_lon=55.239216&search_pageview_id=c0ac477da63f02c2&search_pageview_id=c0ac477da63f02c2&search_selected=true&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0&order=price#map_closed")


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "d4924c9e74"))
    )

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "fcab3ed991 a23c043802"))
    )
    names=element.find_elements_by_class_name("fcab3ed991 a23c043802")
except:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the texts from the ***name*** and ***price*** fields you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAKIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AvqR75YGwAIB0gIkZDQ4MTdjZDctYzIyNC00N2RlLWJhYjItZDU1YTAwMGU2M2Q12AIF4AIB&sid=8005d0cc6b75af8d0d2e74451b73cb8b&aid=304142&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAKIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AvqR75YGwAIB0gIkZDQ4MTdjZDctYzIyNC00N2RlLWJhYjItZDU1YTAwMGU2M2Q12AIF4AIB%26sid%3D8005d0cc6b75af8d0d2e74451b73cb8b%26sb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%26&ss=Jumeirah%2C+Dubai%2C+Dubai+Emirate%2C+United+Arab+Emirates&is_ski_area=&checkin_year=2022&checkin_month=8&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2022&checkout_month=8&checkout_monthday=3&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&map=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&ss_raw=jum&ac_position=1&ac_langcode=en&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=941&dest_type=district&place_id_lat=25.205553&place_id_lon=55.239216&search_pageview_id=c0ac477da63f02c2&search_pageview_id=c0ac477da63f02c2&search_selected=true&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0&order=price#map_closed'})
  names = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='title']")))]
  prices = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='price-and-discounted-price'] > span")))]
  for i,j in zip(names, prices):
    print(f"{i} hotel price is {j}")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Royal Prestige Hotel hotel price is ₹ 10,871
  Rove La Mer Beach hotel price is ₹ 10,328
  Dubai Marine Beach Resort & Spa hotel price is ₹ 12,133
  Roda Beach Resort hotel price is ₹ 16,525
  Bespoke Residences - 3 Bedroom Waikiki Townhouses hotel price is ₹ 20,395
  Walking distance to Burj al Arab - 1BR Lamtara 2 hotel price is ₹ 16,724
  Mandarin Oriental Jumeira, Dubai hotel price is ₹ 18,108
  Four Seasons Resort Dubai at Jumeirah Beach hotel price is ₹ 20,003
  Bulgari Resort, Dubai hotel price is ₹ 78,274
  Spacious Villa! hotel price is ₹ 62,619
  Palm Beach Hotel hotel price is ₹ 64,794
  York International Hotel hotel price is ₹ 86,971
  Moon , Backpackers , Partition for Couples and for singles hotel price is ₹ 208,731
  Hafez Hotel Apartments Al Ras Metro Station hotel price is ₹ 2,022
  Grand Pearl Hostel For Boys hotel price is ₹ 2,131
  Time Palace Hotel Branch hotel price is ₹ 3,131
  Hostel Youth hotel price is ₹ 3,157
  Grand Mayfair Hotel hotel price is ₹ 3,601
  Explore Old Dubai, Souks, Tastings, Museums hotel price is ₹ 4,592
  Panorama Hotel Bur Dubai hotel price is ₹ 3,674
  Zain International Hotel hotel price is ₹ 3,827
  Panorama Hotel Deira hotel price is ₹ 3,870
  Decent Boys Hostel in center of Bur Dubai next to Burjuman metro Station with all FREE Facilities hotel price is ₹ 3,875
  Brand New Boys Hostel 1 min walk from Burjuman Metro Station EXIT-4 with all Brand New Furnishings & Free Facilities hotel price is ₹ 3,914
  OYO 338 Transworld Hotel hotel price is ₹ 3,914
  ```

PS: Following this solution you can similarly extract the **location** and **link** texts as well and dump in a JSON format.