# Selenium - get all child elements from div class

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I want to get the values contained in the span class with value "indigo-text descfont" for the following:

```
<div id="WineDetailContent"> event
 <span class="blue-text codefont">...</span>
 <span class="indigo-text descfont">Alsace</span>
 <br>
 <span class="blue-text codefont">...</span>
 <span class="indigo-text descfont">2014</span>
 <br>
</div>
```

So that I get **Alsace** and **2014**.
I have tried using the following:

```
details = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'WineDetailContent')]")
res = details.find_element_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@class,'indigo-text descfont')]")
print(res.text)
```

But it only returns the first needed value, i.e. **Alsace**.
How is it possible to get **2014** as well?

Comment: On XPATH when you are looking for something inside an element you have to use (a dot) ".//xx" , that means it will looking for on the element, not "//xx" on the root

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

```
<div id="WineDetailContent">
    ...
    <span class="indigo-text descfont">Alsace</span>
    <br>
    ...
    <span class="indigo-text descfont">2014</span>
    <br>
</div>
```

Both the desired texts are within the decendants `<span class="indigo-text descfont">` of their ancestor `<div id="WineDetailContent">`

---

### Solution

To print the texts from the *`<span class="indigo-text descfont">`* elements you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#WineDetailContent span.indigo-text.descfont")])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='WineDetailContent']//span[@class='indigo-text descfont']")])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_xpath` return single WebElement. You need to use `find_elements_by_xpath` to select both elements:

```
details = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id ='WineDetailContent']")
res = details.find_elements_by_xpath("./span[@class = 'indigo-text descfont']")
for i in res:
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are missing an (s) in find element, you need to use find_elements.

In general when we apply find element

```py
element.find_element_by_xxxx(selector)
```

we will get back the first element that matches our selector.

however in case of more items you can use find elements

```py
element.find_elements_by_xxxx(selector)
```

the find elements will return a list of all elements that matches our selector.