# Selenium: find elements by classname returns only one item instead of all

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, list-comprehension

The code below sometimes returns one (1) element, sometimes all, and sometimes none. For it to work for my application I need it to return all the matching elements in the page

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def villanovan():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    url = 'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://villanovan.com/&strip=0&vwsrc=0'
    url_2 = 'https://villanovan.com/'
    driver.get(url_2)
    a = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "homeheadline")
    titles = [i.text for i in a if len(i.text) != 0]
    links = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in a if len(i.text) != 0]
    return [titles, links]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(villanovan())
```

I was expecting a list with multiple links and article titles, but recieved a list with the first element found, not all elements found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the value of *`href`* attributes you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://villanovan.com/")
  time.sleep(3)
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.homeheadline[href]")])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://villanovan.com/")
  time.sleep(3)
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='homeheadline' and @href]")])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://villanovan.com/22105/sports/villanova-goes-cold-in-clutch-against-no-14-marquette/', 'https://villanovan.com/22102/sports/villanova-bests-marquette-in-blowout-win-73-54/', 'https://villanovan.com/22098/news/decarbonizing-villanova-a-town-hall-on-fossil-fuel-divestment/', 'https://villanovan.com/22096/news/biology-professors-granted-1-million-for-wetlands-research/', 'https://villanovan.com/22093/news/students-create-the-space-supporting-sex-education/', 'https://villanovan.com/22098/news/decarbonizing-villanova-a-town-hall-on-fossil-fuel-divestment/', 'https://villanovan.com/22096/news/biology-professors-granted-1-million-for-wetlands-research/', 'https://villanovan.com/22044/culture/julia-staniscis-leaning-on-letters/', 'https://villanovan.com/22032/culture/villanova-sorority-recruitment-recap/', 'https://villanovan.com/22105/sports/villanova-goes-cold-in-clutch-against-no-14-marquette/', 'https://villanovan.com/22102/sports/villanova-bests-marquette-in-blowout-win-73-54/', 'https://villanovan.com/21932/opinion/villanova-should-be-free-for-families-earning-less-than-100000/', 'https://villanovan.com/21897/opinion/grasshoppergate-the-state-of-villanova-dining/', 'https://villanovan.com/22105/sports/villanova-goes-cold-in-clutch-against-no-14-marquette/', 'https://villanovan.com/22102/sports/villanova-bests-marquette-in-blowout-win-73-54/', 'https://villanovan.com/22093/news/students-create-the-space-supporting-sex-education/', 'https://villanovan.com/22090/news/mlk-day-of-service/', 'https://villanovan.com/22087/news/university-updates-covid-procedures/']
  ```