# Webscraping using Beautiful Soup returns empty list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I´m trying to scrape the price information for the products in the site using Beautiful Soup: 'https://www.compracerta.com.br/celulares-e-smartphones?page=1'
But the price returns an empty list i.e. `[]`.

Below my code:

````
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import math
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession, AsyncHTMLSession
from lxml import etree
import xlwt

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url_pag='https://www.compracerta.com.br/celulares-e-smartphones?page=1'
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
executable_path = r'C:\Users\vinig\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
browser.get(url_pag)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
produtos = soup.find_all('div', class_="gallery-container shelf prateleira default n12colunas")
           
for produto in produtos:
         marca = produto.find('a', attrs={'class':"image"})
         preco = produto.find('div', attrs={'class':"price"})```
````

The result is:

[image: Price is empty]

The Elements Page is:

[image: Element Page]

Comment: post the error code in text form as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape the *image* and *price* information of the products from the [**website**](https://www.compracerta.com.br/celulares-e-smartphones?page=1) you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.compracerta.com.br/celulares-e-smartphones?page=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  images = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article.box-produto a.prod-info")]
  prices = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article.box-produto a.prod-info p span.por > span")]
  for i,j in zip(images, prices):
    print(f"Image: {i} Price: {j}")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/iphone-12-64gb-azul-2081266/p Price: R$ 3.849,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/smartphone-samsung-galaxy-a03s-64gb-4gb-ram-4g-wi-fi-dual-chip-camera-tripla---selfie-5mp-6-5--preto-2074884/p Price: R$ 779,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/iphone-11-128gb---preto-2049241/p Price: R$ 3.299,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/iphone-11-128gb---branco-2049240/p Price: R$ 3.299,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/smartphone-motorola-moto-g32-128gb-4gb-ram-65---preto-2110182/p Price: R$ 999,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/smartphone-motorola-moto-g32-128gb-4gb-ram-65---rose-2110183/p Price: R$ 999,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/smartphone-motorola-moto-edge-30-ultra-256gb-12gb-ram-camera-tripla-200-mp-ois-50-mp-12-mp-tela-6-7--white-2103032/p Price: R$ 4.999,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/smartphone-motorola-moto-g52-128gb-4gb-ram-6-6%E2%80%9D-cam-tripla-50mp-8mp-2mp-selfie-16mp---branco-2096318/p Price: R$ 1.349,00
  Image: https://www.compracerta.com.br/moto-g82-5g-2096006/p Price: R$ 1.999,00
  ```

Comment: Great! I just add a time.sleep(5) after the click action button to take a time to capture the informations! Tks!