# How to get the value of a nested td elements using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am trying to get the value of the 3rd `<td>` tag in each `<tr>` in the table.

I tried:

```
math_grade = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,'./body/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody'))).text
print(math_grade)
```

but it didn't work, knowing that, this table only shows after a search so i added a `sleep(5)` before this line of code runs.

[image]

Comment: want to get the 3rd <td> in each <tr>

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about _3rd tag in each in the table_?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get *values from each 3rd cell of each table row*

```
math_grades = [td.text for td in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//tr/td[3]')))]
```

P.S. Note that to use XPath as locator you need to pass `By.XPATH` selector type but not `By.TAG_NAME`

P.P.S. Add HTML-code samples as text, not as image-file

Answer (score 0):

To print the text from the 3rd `<td>` from each `<tr>` instead of `presence_of_element_located()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using xpath and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody//tr//td[@class='grade']//following-sibling::td[1]")))])
  ```
- Using xpath and *`get_attribute()`* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody//tr//td[@class='grade']//following-sibling::td[1]")))])
  ```