# Using text attribute returns empty string with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, text, webdriver

I tried to collect some text with selenium webdriver using python and I found that
`something.text` collect empty string, but `something.get_attribute(name="innerText")` collect value I want. Why is this happening ?

```
something = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "block-mega-child-cats")
tag = something.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
for i in tag:
    print(i.get_attribute(name="innerText"))
```

This part of code works perfectly, but I can't understand why `.text` doesn't.

Comment: Can you provide a URL or HTML snippet? What do you mean by does not work?

Comment: Try using `i.getText()`

Answer (score 0):

To collect all the texts you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following solution:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".block-mega-child-cats a")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='block-mega-child-cats']//a")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```