# How to get tweets in twitter using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, twitter, css-selectors

I want to get tweets in python by selenium but get attribute didnt work for me. Here is my code. can you help me to fix it?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://twitter.com/elonmusk")
time.sleep(3)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 4
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    tweet = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='id__z5kb0qs2bgp']").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for grabbing the tweet text:

```
tweets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]')
for i in tweets:
    print(i.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract tweets you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following locator strategies:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('http://twitter.com/elonmusk')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='tweetText'] span")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('http://twitter.com/elonmusk')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='tweetText']//span")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```