# How to extract informations from a li tag with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a website i want to scrape but the information am looking for is contained in an "li" tag. This "li" tag has no class or id. Also all the "li" tags are contained in an "ul" tag without class or id. There are about 25 "li" tags contained in one "ul". How do i iterate this "li" tag to get all the informations contained in the  25 "li" tags. Meanwhile I want to do this with selenium

Pictorial representation
[image]

I want to extract the text elements contained in the "div". For example first "div" has '1,000,000 PPE Solutions'. I want to extract such text for all the "li" tags.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required information is within the `<a>` tag which is within individual `<li>` tags having a parent `<ul>` tag within:

```
<div class="item-list">
```

---

### Solution

To extract all the information from all the `<li>` tags ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item-list > ul li div.field-content > a[href]")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item-list']/ul//li//div[@class='field-content']/a[@href]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath in selenium

```
//div[contains(@class, 'tradename')]/..
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Ketan Pardeshi but I still want to extract all the text elements contained in the "li" tags. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

This will list all the `li` tags:

XPATH:

```
.//div[@class='item-list']/ul/li
```

CSS_SELECTOR:

```
.item-list ul li
```

Also, within the `li` tag which information do you want to access?, for that , you need to post the URL or the complete HTML source.

Answer (score -1):

```
    from selenium.webdriver import webdriver , keys
       driver =  webdriver.chrome()
       driver.get("https://your_target_site.com")
       my_li_elements = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('li')
       my_li_elements_text = my_li_elements.text

    or

    my_ul = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul")
    my_li_elements =my_ul.find_element_by_css_selector("li")
    for li in my_li_elements:
        text = li.text
        print(text)



 

   i hope it will help you
```

Comment: Hi @biswajit panda i got a type error. here ` for li in my_li_elements:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`

Comment: selenium not suport anymore find_element_by_css_selector