# How to get all the elements from same class using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, list-comprehension

I am trying to get span elements from same class names. I am trying to click the lastest avaible days in calender.

My code is :

```
days = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'BookingCalendar-date--bookable')
avaibledays = days.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'BookingCalendar-day')
for i in avaibledays:
    print(i.text)
```

This work for 1 class when I try to change the days variable like this:

```
days = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'BookingCalendar-date--bookable')
```

I can't get all.

There is a calander html.

[image]

I want to click a span at lastest class name is = `"BookingCalendar-date--bookable"`

Span names and class same for `Booking-Calendar-date--unavaible`

So basicly I'm trying to get multiple span elements from classes name is `BookingCalendar-date--bookable`. The span elements have a same class name it's = `BookingCalendar-day`

Comment: add more details, is not clear want you want

Comment: I want to get and last avaible days from calendar.Avaible days class is "BookingCalendar-date--bookable".But calendar have 10 active day.So we have 10 class with same name.I want to reach span which ones is bookable.Sorry for my bad eng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the texts from all the *`<td class="BookingCalendar-date--bookable " ...>`* using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.BookingCalendar-date--bookable span.BookingCalendar-day")])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='BookingCalendar-date--bookable ']//span[@class='BookingCalendar-day']")])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```