# I can't parse the item. Selenium Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I do this. First I parsed the main block, and then some of the elements from it, but I get the same element. Here is the code:

```
driver.get("site")
time.sleep(3)

diary_main = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='diary-day']")
for i in diary_main:
    diary_date = i.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='diary-day-date']").get_attribute("data-date")
    print(diary_date)
    print(i.text)
    time.sleep(2)
```

**diary_date outputs the same item**
Sample HTML:

```
<div class="diary-day">
     <div class="diary-day-date" data-date="Sunday"></div>
</div>
<div class="diary-day">
     <div class="diary-day-date" data-date="Monday"></div>
</div>
<div class="diary-day">
     <div class="diary-day-date" data-date="Tuesday"></div>
</div>
<div class="diary-day">
     <div class="diary-day-date" data-date="Wednesday"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: @undetected Selenium added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably problem with *diary_main* variable. It can't persist all the elements or timing issues. You can try this,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("site")

#wait for diary_main elements to be present
diary_main = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='diary-day']")))

for i in diary_main:
    diary_date = i.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='diary-day-date']").get_attribute("data-date")
    print(diary_date)
    print(i.text) 
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have a small addition, and if I want to continue searching for elements through `i`, what should I do? Through the normal option error

Answer (score 0):

To extract the values of the *`data-date`* attribute ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("data-date") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.diary-day > div.diary-day-date")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("data-date") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='diary-day']/div[@class='diary-day-date']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```